# How to get the boolean value of an inequality involving an InterpolatingFunction?

Tags: interpolation, boolean-computation

Here's the code:

```
yan = FunctionInterpolation[x^2, {x, -1, 1}];
FullSimplify[yan[x] > -1, -1 < x < 1]
```

Needless to say, what I expect to see in the output is "True", but `FullSimplify` doesn't seem  to work. What function should I turn to?

---

@J.M. @belisarius @acl

囧…A very simple solution suddenly struck me, it is:

```
yan = FunctionInterpolation[x^2, {x, -1, 1}];
MinValue[{yan[x], -1 < x < 1},x]>-1
```

Comment: Huh? "seems not to work" is correct? I just delete it because of my language sense…OK, let me add it back.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" as you added is more standard, but in my opinion "seems not to work" is also acceptable and understandable.

Comment: In fact I've become confused after I searched the Internet, so I turned to the standard form to be on the safe side 囧.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I ocasionally recall this question I asked 10 years ago, and notice nowadays `ResourceFunction["InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise"]` or `InterpolationToPiecewise` in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212753/1871) seems to be the best choice to resolve the problem:

```
yan = FunctionInterpolation[x^2, {x, -1, 1}];
yanAnalytic = ResourceFunction["InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise"][yan, x]
FullSimplify[yanAnalytic > -1, -1 < x < 1]
(* True *)
```

This method perfectly handles the troublesome case [shown by J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9126/how-to-get-the-boolean-value-of-an-inequality-involving-an-interpolatingfunction#comment26308_9131), too:

```
func = FunctionInterpolation[1/(1 + x^2), {x, -2, 2}];
funcAnalytic = ResourceFunction["InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise"][func, x];
Simplify[funcAnalytic < 3/2, -2 < x < 2]
(* True *)
```

BTW, I don't evaluate my `MinValue` method in the question as the best, because it's essentially a numeric method. `MinValue` has secretly called `NMinimize` internally!:

```
Trace[MinValue[{yan[x], -1 < x < 1}, x], __NMinimize, TraceInternal -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by explicitly constructing the [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html) corresponding to `yan`, and then using `FullSimplify`:

```
yin = InterpolatingPolynomial[Transpose[Flatten /@ {yan[[3]],yan[[4]]}],x];
FullSimplify[yin > -1, -1 < x < 1]
(*True*)
```

Why does this work? Because `yan` actually has a list of points:

```
FullForm[yan]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

so I can extract them with `Transpose[Flatten /@ {yan[[3]],yan[[4]]}]` and use them to construct a polynomial, which does the same thing as the interpolation function but which `FullSimplify` can now handle.

Maybe there's a better way to construct the `InterpolatingPolynomial` but this works.

Answer (score 6):

The following is basically the same @acl did, but using the package `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` which (in principle) will behave better than peeking at the internal structures when Mma version changes.

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
yan = FunctionInterpolation[x^2, {x, -1, 1}];

yin = InterpolatingPolynomial[Transpose[Flatten /@
                                {InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates@yan, 
                                 InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid@yan}], x];
FullSimplify[yin > -1, -1 < x < 1]
(*
  True
*)
```

Comment: very nice. how come I have less votes than you though, despite being first and explaining details?! Not fair! :)

Comment: @acl That was because I forgot to upvote your answer. Easy to correct! :D

Comment: really, I was joking!

Comment: In fact, you don't need to load the package if you remember the actual syntax being used internally; in this case, it's `yan["Coordinates"]` and `yan["ValuesOnGrid"]` that can be used directly. Still, this works only because the original function was well approximated by a polynomial. In general, a polynomial interpolant can be more oscillatory than the *piecewise* polynomial interpolant used by `InterpolatingFunction[]`; be careful!

Comment: @J.M. yes, it was intended just for this case

Comment: @J.M. So, in fact this is still not a perfect solution for this problem? Huh…whatever! It's enough for me, in my case it won't make a big difference even if `InterpolatingPolynomial` causes some oscillation. By the way, where can I find those syntax in the help?

Comment: @xzczd, definitely not the perfect solution. To use the classical example (due to Carl Runge), try `FunctionInterpolation[1/(1 + x^2), {x, -2, 2}]`. `InterpolatingPolynomial[]` will fail spectacularly to reproduce the original interpolating function.

Comment: @J.M. Haha, it's really spectacular. By the way, where can I find those syntax ("Coordinates" "ValuesOnGrid" etc.) in the help?

Comment: @xzczd, they aren't (explicitly) documented, but try looking up `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` in the docs.

Comment: @xzczd Search for `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` in this site. You'll find some nice applications for it