# Alternative to Series

Tags: symbolic, series-expansion

Here is a sample of my code:

```
sys = 
  {
    Subscript[x, 1]'[t] == Subscript[x, 2][t], 
    Subscript[x, 2]'[t] == Subscript[x, 2][t]*Subscript[x, 3][t], 
    Subscript[x, 3]'[t] == Subscript[x, 4][t],
    Subscript[x, 4]'[t] == Subscript[x, 4][t]*(Subscript[x, 2][t]/Subscript[x, 1][t] + 1) + Subscript[x, 4][t]
  }

ic = {Subscript[x, 1][0] == 0, Subscript[x, 2][0] == 0,
      Subscript[x, 3][0] == 1, Subscript[x, 4][0] == 0}

Series[
  {Subscript[x, 1][t], Subscript[x, 2][t],Subscript[x, 3][t], Subscript[x, 4][t]} /. 
    First @ DSolve[Join[sys, ic], {Subscript[x, 1][t], Subscript[x, 2][t],Subscript[x, 3][t], Subscript[x, 4][t]}, t], 
  {t, 0, 1}];
```

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_1'(t) =x_2(t)\\ 
x_2'(t) = x_2(t)x_3(t)\\ 
x_3'(t) = x_4(t)\\
x_4'(t) = x_4(t)\left ( \frac{x_2(t)}{x_1(t)} + 1\right ) + x_4(t)\\ 
(x_1(0) = 0,x_2(0)=1,x_3(0) = 0, x_4(0) = 0 )
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I am trying to find the solution to a system of nonlinear differential equations which has a singular point at $t = 0$, so I want to use a series solution. Now I have noticed that *Mathematica's* Series command assumes a function is differentiable, so I wasn't able to get an answer. Because of singularities, is it possible to get a solution with arbitrary coeffecticents $$f(t) = \sum a_n t^n$$

The above is just an example, my actual system is far bigger than this.

**Addendum**: This is to clarify the singularity in the fourth DE.

Let $x_1 = \sum c_n t^n = c_0 + c_1 t + \dots$, then $x_1(0) = 0 \implies c_0 = 0$.

Let $x_3 = \sum a_n t^n = a_0 + a_1 t + \dots$

$x_3' = x_4 = a_1 + 2a_2t + \dots$. This means $x_4(0) = 0 \implies a_1 = 0.$

So now we may (this won't change the nature of the problem) add *another* initial condition $x_4'(0) = 1$.

This means the last equation in our system is

$$2a_2 + 3a_3t + \dots = x_4'(t) = (2a_2t + 3a_3t^2\dots)\left ( \frac{x_2(t)}{c_1 t + c_2t^2+\dots} + 1\right ) + (0 + 2a_2t + \dots)$$

Since I only want a finite sum (of the power series), everything would be in terms of coefficients of the power series of $x_1$ and $x_4$, the nth term from L'Hopital's Rule or otherwise.

Comment: I think you forgot 2 initial conditions in the code?

Comment: @xzczd, yes I did, but that's a typo.

Comment: Do you need a numeric series solution or a symbolic series solution?

Comment: In your fourth equation `x1[t] `is found in the denominator, while the initial condition is `x1[0]==0 `which is a contradiction.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. `DSolve` can not solve the system as posed, so what are you trying to accomplish by wrapping it in series?

Comment: @xzczd, well I have initial conditions, so numeric series solution is the only possible output.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, no I am trying to approximate it with a power series, there is no contradiction.

Comment: If a numeric series solution is desired, then I think this is a possible duplicate of [Series expansion of InterpolatingFunction obtained from NDSolve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64502/1871)

Comment: @xzczd, that's only for simple linear ODE. I have a *system* of *nonlinear* DEs.

Comment: There still appears confusion over the singular point. I am going to edit to make it clearer.

Comment: @xzczd, I should mention I tried NDSolve on a linear system and it didn't' work.

Comment: Your code still contains typos, you'd better fix them. The only troublesome part is the `x[1][0] == 0` condition, if an approximate nonzero condition like `x[1][0] == 10^-10` is acceptable, then the method in the post linked above will handle your equation set.

Comment: @xzczd, can you point out the typos? The problem with Series[] (which is used in your link), is that it assumes the solution is differentiable first, then it finds the series.

Comment: I fixed it for you. `NDSolve` outputs an `InterpolatingFunction`, which is already a differentiable approximation. Well, I can post an answer if you like, the graph under your i.c.s isn't interesting though.

Comment: Did you change the $x_1(0)$?

Comment: @Hawk Yes. Seems that it can be arbitrary small. Just tried `x[1][0] == 10^-160`.

Comment: No, there is a contradiction, since there is the an undefined ratio x4/x1 in the initial point already.

Comment: I remained confused as to what your question is. Are you seeking some approach other that the fairly obvious one of plugging in the series and attempting to solve the resulting nonlinear algebraic system?

Comment: @george2079, that is what I am doing. But the computer doesn't know how to get around the singularity  like I do.