# Series expansion of NDSolve solution produced by shooting method

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, series-expansion

The ODE I need to solve is

```
eqn1 = t x'[t] - (-x[t] + y[t]);
eqn2 = t y'[t] - (-5 t^2/x[t]^2 + x[t] - y[t]);
sol = NDSolve[{eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0, x[0] == y[0], x[1] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0,1},
Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
                                 {x[1] == 1, y[1] == 2/100 + 91/16000}}];
```

Then I want to expand my solutions, say `x'[t]` around `t=1`. Then I encounter the same problem as described in [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64502/series-expansion-of-interpolatingfunction-obtained-from-ndsolve). But my method is `shooting`, I can not switch it to `ExplicitRungeKutta`. I do not find any options to change `DifferenceOrder` in `shooting` method.

> so my question is how to increase the `DifferenceOrder` to get the
>   correct series expansion.

Comment: What are you looking to do with the series expansion?  `NDSolve` solves the equation numerically.  It computes the value of `x[t]` at discrete points in time.  It does not compute a function, just function values at certain discrete times.  You can't get a Taylor expansion from this.  If you are looking for a series expansion of the solution, why don't you try to get it symbolically instead of first solving the equation using a numerical method? http://math.stackexchange.com/q/200582/12384

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks so much. this really works. I did not even know this smart way to get the approximated solution. Why do not you just paste your comment into the answer, so I can end the discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd checked [the document of shooting method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#659822336) carefully, you would notice that a `Method` can be added inside `Method`:

```
eqn1 = t x'[t] - (-x[t] + y[t]);
eqn2 = t y'[t] - (-5 t^2/x[t]^2 + x[t] - y[t]);
sol = Quiet@
   NDSolve[{eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0, x[0] == y[0], x[1] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", 
      Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 9}, 
      "StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[1] == 1, y[1] == 2/100 + 91/16000}},
        InterpolationOrder -> All];

xs[t_] = Normal@Series[x[t] /. sol, {t, 1, 9}][[1]]
```

> ```
> 1. + 0.974309 (-1 + t) - 1.03854 (-1 + t)^2 + 1.07247 (-1 + t)^3 - 
>  1.52337 (-1 + t)^4 + 2.3813 (-1 + t)^5 - 4.0006 (-1 + t)^6 + 
>  6.80946 (-1 + t)^7 - 10.1406 (-1 + t)^8 + 8.91923 (-1 + t)^9
> ```

Sadly, the Taylor expansion of the solution at $t=1$ seems not to converge:

```
Plot[{x[t] /. sol, xs[t]}, {t, 0.03, 1}]
```

[image]