# Numerically approximating the series of the solution to a PDE

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion, numerical-value

Suppose I had a PDE such as the heat equation in two variables, and I want to solve it with mathematica, and ask it to return me a series expansion of the solution. For example,

```
fsoln = NDSolve[{D[f[x,y],x]+D[f[x,y],y,y]==0,f[0,y]==1,f[x,0]==x+1},f,{x,0,10},{y,0,10}]
```

This returns `fsoln` as an interpolating function. If I wanted to get a series expansion to say $x^{10}$ while keeping $y$ constant and $y=1$, I use

```
Series[Evaluate[f[x,1]/.fsoln],{x,0,10}]
```

which gives me the output `1+O(x)^11`. This is clearly wrong, since the solution to the heat equation is not a constant! How can this problem be solved?

---

From a comment in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64502/series-expansion-of-interpolatingfunction-obtained-from-ndsolve) I tried to use

```
Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 5}
```

but it does not seem to help to increase the number of terms (the coefficients of $x^4$ and above terms seem to always be $0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
F = NDSolveValue[{D[f[x, y], x] + D[f[x, y], y] == 0, f[0, y] == 1, f[x, 0] == x + 1}, f, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

which gives the interpolation `F[x,y]`

```
Fs=Series[F[x, 1], {x, 0, 10}]//Normal
(*1. - 2.68882*10^-17 x - 0.263942 x^2 + 3.02651 x^3*)
```

evaluates a cubic series approximation (`O[x^11]`)!

```
Fser = Series[F[x, 1], {x, 0, 10}] // Normal;
Plot[{F[x, 1], Max[1, x], Fser}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}]
```

[image]

which fits only for small x!

Comment: That's better, but surely the solution to the heat equation isn't a cubic polynomial! It is not even a polynomial at all, so shouldn't we expect to see $x^4,x^5,\dots,x^{10}$ terms as well?

Comment: I would expect a piecewise linear solution, but I didn't check your model!

Comment: I think the issue here, as explained by one of the answers in the linked question, is that `NDSolve` only gives interpolating function solutions with fourth order derivatives equal to $0$. The correct solution is certainly not piecewise linear or cubic.

Comment: The equation `D[f[x, y], x] + D[f[x, y], y] == 0`does not look like the heat equation. The letter is second order.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Of course, there was a typo in the question. It is fixed now.

Comment: @ YiFan Please check the initial and boundary conditions. In which range x you want to solve your problem? Perhaps you need NeumannValue to describe your problem well?

Comment: There is still one typo.