# What is the most accurate way of getting the highest derivative from NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, precision-and-accuracy

I would like to compare my simulations in Mathematica to measured data. I measure acceleration but for simulations the starting point is displacement. How does one get accurate simulations of higher derivatives of the solutions to differential equations?

Here is a simple example of a simulation where we have the exact solution. (My actual problems are much more complicated). First I define a few parameters and then get exact results for displacement, velocity and acceleration.

```
vals = {
   a -> 100, (* frequency *)
   b -> 10,    (* damping *)
   y0 -> 1,    (* initial displacement *)
   v0 -> 0      (* initial velocity *)
   };
tmax = 0.5 ;(* simulation time *)
SetOptions[Plot, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 2.5 72];
d0 = y[t] /. 
   First@DSolve[{y''[t] + 2 b y'[t] + (2 π a)^2 y[t] == 0,
      y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y[t], t];
de = d0 /. vals;
ve = D[d0, t] /. vals;
ae = D[d0, {t, 2}] /. vals;
Row[{
  Plot[de, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[ve, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[ae, {t, 0, tmax}]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The three plots are displacement, velocity and acceleration. The scales are very different but are noted in the next stage.

**One equation**

I use one equation in the simulation using `NDSolve` and look at the errors between the displacement velocity and acceleration. The errors are normalised so that the functions being differenced are of order 1.

```
vmax = 600; amax = 400000;
d1 = y /. First@NDSolve[{
       y''[t] + 2 b y'[t] + (2 \[Pi] a)^2 y[t] == 0,
       y[0] == y0, y'[0] == v0} /. vals, y, {t, 0, tmax}];

Row[{Plot[d1[t] - de, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[(d1'[t] - ve)/vmax, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[(d1''[t] - ae)/amax, {t, 0, tmax}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The errors in displacement and velocity are of order 10^-7 which is reasonable but the error in acceleration is of order 10^-5.  The errors in acceleration are particularly uneven with significant spikes.

**Two equations**

The differential equation is now split into two equations, one for displacement and one for velcity.

```
{d2, v2} = {y, v} /. First@NDSolve[{
       y'[t] == v[t],
       v'[t] + 2 b v[t] + (2 \[Pi] a)^2 y[t] == 0,
       y[0] == y0, v[0] == v0} /. vals, {y, v}, {t, 0, tmax}];
Row[{
  Plot[d2[t] - de, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[(v2[t] - ve)/vmax, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[(v2'[t] - ae)/amax, {t, 0, tmax}]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The accuracy is worse for the displacement and velocity and no better for the acceleration.

**Three equations**

Here we have differential equations for the velocity and acceleration. The interaction between these derivatives is expressed as an algebraic equation.

```
{d3, v3, ac3} = {y, v, ac} /. First@NDSolve[{
       v'[t] == ac[t],
       y'[t] == v[t],
       ac[t] + 2 b v[t] + (2 π a)^2 y[t] == 0,
       y[0] == y0, v[0] == v0} /. vals, {y, v, ac}, {t, 0, tmax}];
Row[{
  Plot[d3[t] - de, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[(v3[t] - ve)/vmax, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[(ac3[t] - ae)/amax, {t, 0, tmax}]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For this simulation the three results are of order 10^-6 and there are no spikes on any of the simulations. I guess the issues I am seeing are to due to the type of interpolation used. Derivatives of interpolation functions do not work well.

This suggests that the third approach is best if I want about equal errors for displacement, velocity and acceleration. Is this the best approach? Are there other approaches to getting a good second derivative?

If one had a third order, or forth order differential equation (I sometimes do) should one extend this method?

***Edit***

Following the suggestion using the answer from I M I have investigated setting the interpolation order. The information from Help is not very clear it states

> Use InterpolationOrder->All to get interpolation the same order as the method:

Can anyone explain what this means? What are orders of the method?

I have rerun the case with one equation. This gives:

```
vmax = 600; amax = 400000;
d1a = y /. First@NDSolve[{
       y''[t] + 2 b y'[t] + (2 \[Pi] a)^2 y[t] == 0,
       y[0] == y0, y'[0] == v0} /. vals, y, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     InterpolationOrder -> All];

Row[{Plot[d1a[t] - de, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[(d1a'[t] - ve)/vmax, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[(d1a''[t] - ae)/amax, {t, 0, tmax}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
This is now good with similar errors for all derivatives.

****Edit 2****
Here is another approach suggested by Michael E2 that uses `InterpolationOrder-> All, Method->"ImplicitRungeKutta"`

```
vmax = 600; amax = 400000;
d1b = y /. First@NDSolve[{
       y''[t] + 2 b y'[t] + (2 \[Pi] a)^2 y[t] == 0,
       y[0] == y0, y'[0] == v0} /. vals, y, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     InterpolationOrder -> All, Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta"];

Row[{Plot[d1b[t] - de, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[(d1b'[t] - ve)/vmax, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[(d1b''[t] - ae)/amax, {t, 0, tmax}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
This gives an error of 10^-15 which is as much as one can hope for.

A further suggestion by J.M's ttechnical difficulties is to use `Interpolation -> All, Method->"StiffnessSwitching"`

```
vmax = 600; amax = 400000;
d1c = y /. First@NDSolve[{
       y''[t] + 2 b y'[t] + (2 \[Pi] a)^2 y[t] == 0,
       y[0] == y0, y'[0] == v0} /. vals, y, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     InterpolationOrder -> All, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];

Row[{Plot[d1c[t] - de, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[(d1c'[t] - ve)/vmax, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[(d1c''[t] - ae)/amax, {t, 0, tmax}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
This is rather disappointing as there are spikes showing a huge error. However, if you zoom in, ignoring the spikes the error is about 10^-8.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64502/1871

Comment: As to `InterpolationOrder->All`, have you read this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13836/1871

Comment: Try using `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` with `InterpolationOrder -> All`.

Comment: Consider `NDSolve[..., InterpolationOrder -> All, Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase interpolation order in `NDSolve[]`, <del>not sure, looks like it should be `order + 2` or</del> use `All`:

```
vmax = 600; amax = 400000;
d1 = y /. First@NDSolve[{
       y''[t] + 2 b y'[t] + (2 \[Pi] a)^2 y[t] == 0,
       y[0] == y0, y'[0] == v0} /. vals, y, {t, 0, tmax},InterpolationOrder -> 4 (*All*)];
Row[{
  Plot[d1[t] - de, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[(d1'[t] - ve)/vmax, {t, 0, tmax}],
  Plot[(d1''[t] - ae)/amax, {t, 0, 0.5}]}]
```

### Edit

Thanks to @xzczd's comment I've remembered, `"InterpolationOrder"` is related to `"DifferenceOrder"`, not ODE order.

You can use `"ImplicitRungeKutta"` or `"ExplicitRungeKutta"` methods, with custom `"DifferenceOrder"` and `"InterpolationOrder" -> All`.

For example, this is order 20 adaptive step implicit RK (also symplectic):

```
Method->{"ImplicitRungeKutta",DifferenceOrder->20,"Coefficients"->"ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients","ImplicitSolver"->{"Newton",AccuracyGoal->MachinePrecision,PrecisionGoal->MachinePrecision,"IterationSafetyFactor"->1}}
```

You can also use fixed step method:

```
Method->{"TimeIntegration"->{"FixedStep",Method->{"ImplicitRungeKutta",DifferenceOrder->10,"Coefficients"->"ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients","ImplicitSolver"->{"Newton",AccuracyGoal->MachinePrecision,PrecisionGoal->MachinePrecision,"IterationSafetyFactor"->1}}}}
```

For fixed step also set `"StartingStepSize"`, `"MaxStepFraction"` and `"MaxSteps"` options.

Comment: Thanks I have updated the question showing the effect of your suggestion.