# What is the Chebyshev method for `InterpolationFunction`?

Tags: interpolation, implementation-details

With `InterpolationOrder -> All`, some methods of `NDSolve` returns interpolations with `Method -> "Chebyshev"`. E.g.

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1}, x[t], {t, 0, 1},
  InterpolationOrder -> All, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"]
```

What is the Chebyshev method? I couldn't find it explained in the documentation nor on this site. Does `Method -> "Chebyshev"` refer to some widely used method with a more specific name to google?

Comment: Michael E2 had [previously looked into this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=27606056#27606056); apparently a (piecewise) Chebyshev series solution to the DE is being constructed, akin to [chebfun](http://www.chebfun.org/).

Comment: Basically, my understanding is this, based more on textbook descriptions of DE solving than *Mathematica* documentation: `InterpolationOrder -> All` causes `NDSolve` to construct a polynomial of degree equal to the order of the method for each step, and this polynomial is stored as a Chebyshev series in the `InterpolatingFunction`. I tested and the evaluation agrees with the Clenshaw algorithm (at least when using `MachinePrecision`). I used it for [chebInterpolation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114065/), which constructs such an interpolation. (Pls let me know of problems with it.)

Answer (score 9):

I guess my comment should be an answer:

Basically, my understanding is this, based more on textbook descriptions of DE solving (and extensive playing with `Interpolation`) than on Mathematica documentation: `InterpolationOrder -> All` causes `NDSolve` to construct a polynomial of degree equal to the order of the method for each step. For the integration methods `"ExplicitRungeKutta"`, `"ImplicitRungeKutta"`, `"Extrapolation"` and `"DoubleStep"`, this polynomial is stored as a Chebyshev series in the `InterpolatingFunction`.  (For other integration methods, it is stored as a local Taylor Series. When the order of the method is small, cubic Hermite interpolation is used.  See [The only usage for the option InterpolationOrder in NDSolve is to be set to All?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13836/the-only-usage-for-the-option-interpolationorder-in-ndsolve-is-to-be-set-to-all/145853#145853)) I tested the evaluation of the `InterpolatingFunction`, and it agrees with the Clenshaw algorithm (at least when using MachinePrecision).  I presume that is what is used under the hood.

I used the interpolation method `"Chebyshev"` for [`chebInterpolation`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114065/).  Unfortunately, currently one has to construct the `InterpolatingFunction[]` directly.  There is no option setting such as `Method -> "Chebyshev"` supported by `Interpolation`, which I think is a pity.  I think users should have access to all the standard interpolation methods.  The problem with using the undocumented construction via `InterpolatingFunction` is that if you make a mistake, you find out in one of two ways: The `InterpolatingFunction` does not format properly or the kernel crashes.  Maybe sometimes you can get an error message, but I can't seem to recall getting one.

The basic idea is what one would expect.  For each pair of successive grid points $x_i, x_{i+1}$, the Chebyshev series coefficients $\{c_0,c_1,\dots,c_k\}$ are stored in the `InterpolatingFunction[]`; then, scaling $z$ to run from $-1$ to $1$ as $x$ runs from $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$, the polynomial $p(x) = c_0\,T_0(z) + c_1\,T_1(z) + \cdots + c_k\,T_k(z)$, where $T_j(z)$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of order $j$ (`ChebyshevT[j, z]`), is used to interpolate over the interval between the grid points.  It appears that the order of the series $k$ has to be same for each interval in a given `InterpolatingFunction[]`.