# Are derivatives from interpolating functions created by NDSolve using derivatives of the spline or numerics from solving DE

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, implementation-details

For example given the code:

```
s = NDSolve[{y''[x] + Sin[y[x]] y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
  y, {x, 0, 30}]
Plot[Evaluate[{y[x], y'[x], y''[x]} /. s], {x, 0, 30}, 
 PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

giving output
[image]

Are the derivatives shown here the numerical derivatives the `NDSolve` would need to calculate when solving the differential equation, or are the just derivatives determined after the fact from the spline of the interpolating function?

My expectation is that these are just derivatives of the spline but it would be nice if these were the values calculated by `NDSolve`.

Comment: "it would be nice if these were the values calculated by `NDSolve`." - then you need to actually provide the relevant equations for the derivatives, since `y'[x]` is by necessity directly differentiating the `InterpolatingFunction`.

Comment: `Interpolation` can construct an `InterpolatingFunction` that reproduces the values of derivatives as well as those of the function itself. Since this capability exists, I would think that `NDSolve` would provide that information in its `InterpolatingFunction` output. But this is speculation on my part. As an aside, you could use `NDSolveValue[yourEquation, {y, y', y''}, {x, 0, 30}]` to get separate `InterpolatingFunction` objects representing the function and each of its derivatives, right from within `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default type of interpolation produced by `NDSolve` stores for each discrete step the domain abscissa $x_j$, the function value $y(x_j)$, and the derivative values $y^{k}(x_j)$ up to the order of the ODE. In the OP's example, the derivatives stored are $y'(x_j)$ and $y''(x_j)$.
The data structure inside `InterpolatingFunction[<...>]` is shown in
[What's inside InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 4.}}, <>]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4)
and in the code toward the end of this answer,
[Interpolating data with a step](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/interpolating-data-with-a-step/98349#98349).
Part `4` contains the function and derivative data for each step. It is stored in a flat array of the form

```
(*
{y[x0], y'[x0],..., Derivative[k][y][x0],
 y[x1], y'[x1],..., Derivative[k][y][x1],
 ...}
*)
```

The data also contains offsets that indicate where each function/derivative value unit ends. When the order of the ODE is `k = 2`, there are three values per unit `y, y', y''`.

```
yIFN = y /. First[s];
yIFN[[4]]
(*
{Developer`PackedArrayForm,       (* type of data *)
 {0, 3, 6, 9, ... 1407},          (* offsets *)
 {1.`, 0.`, -0.8414709848078965`, (* function/derivative values *)
  0.9999999750347968`, -0.00014493961665665655`, -0.8414709503116456`,
  0.9999999251043933`, -0.00028987922142966306`, -0.8414708813191469`,
  ...,
  0.9989990862203024`,  0.04101857645543858`,    -0.8400880807981383`}}
*)
```

The argument `"ValuesOnGrid"` gives a slice of this data for each of the derivatives computed by `NDSolve` (i.e., `y, y', y''` in the OP example):

```
yIFN["ValuesOnGrid"][[{1, 2, 3, -1}]]
yIFN'["ValuesOnGrid"][[{1, 2, 3, -1}]]
yIFN''["ValuesOnGrid"][[{1, 2, 3, -1}]]

(*       y[x]         |           y'[x]            |         y''[x]
{1.`,                 | {0.`,                      | {-0.8414709848078965`,
 0.9999999750347968`, |  -0.00014493961665665655`, |  -0.8414709503116456`,
 0.9999999251043933`, |  -0.00028987922142966306`, |  -0.8414708813191469`, 
 0.9989990862203024`} |  0.04101857645543858`}     |  -0.8400880807981383`} 
*)
```

Note these values match the data shown for `yIFN[[4]]`.  If you ask for higher derivatives, they are computed from the interpolation. We have 6 values total for each interpolation interval (3 at each end point). They determine a degree 5 interpolant.  Derivatives of order 6 and higher are zero.

```
Derivative[3][yIFN]["ValuesOnGrid"][[{1, 2, 3, -1}]]
Derivative[4][yIFN]["ValuesOnGrid"][[{1, 2, 3, -1}]]
Derivative[5][yIFN]["ValuesOnGrid"][[{1, 2, 3, -1}]]
Derivative[6][yIFN]["ValuesOnGrid"][[{1, 2, 3, -1}]]
(* 
{-146559., -146559., -146559., ..., -0.0565191}
{5.10523*10^9, -5.10523*10^9, -5.10523*10^9, ..., 1.1701}
{-5.92786*10^13, -5.92786*10^13, -5.92786*10^13, ..., 0.366953}
{0., 0., 0., ..., 0.}
*)
```

What looks like numerical instability is probably due to the small step sizes at the beginning:

```
Differences[yIFN["Grid"]][[{1, 2, 3, -1}]]
(*  {{0.000172246}, {0.000172246}, {0.00382697}, {0.0971486}}  *)

Derivative[5][yIFN] // ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> All] &
Derivative[5][yIFN] // ListLinePlot
```

[image]
[image]

*Update*

Another thing worth mentioning is that only one thing is changed in `yIFN` when it is differentiated. The order of the derivative is changed in the `InterpolatingFunction` structure.

```
yIFN''''[[4]] === yIFN[[4]]
(*  True  *)
```

The derivative of the interpolation may be inspected by `Part` or via the `"DerivativeOrder"` method:

```
yIFN[[2, 6]]
yIFN''[[2, 6]]
yIFN''''[[2, 6]]
(*
  0
  {2}
  {4}
*)

yIFN''''["DerivativeOrder"]
(*  Derivative[4]  *)
```

Related Q&A:

These deal with variations due to `InterpolationOrder -> All`:

- [The only usage for the option InterpolationOrder in NDSolve is to be set to All?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13836/the-only-usage-for-the-option-interpolationorder-in-ndsolve-is-to-be-set-to-all/145853#145853)
- [What is the Chebyshev method for `InterpolationFunction`?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120267/what-is-the-chebyshev-method-for-interpolationfunction/151755#151755)

Comment: Does changing `InterpolationOrder` when calling `NDSolve` cause Mathematica to store higher-order derivatives in the `InterpolatingFunction`?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert `InterpolationOrder -> All` will change things; but a lower `InterpolationOrder ->3`  seems to have no effect; and a higher `InterpolationOrder -> 7` does the same thing as `All`. `InterpolationOrder -> All` will store an interpolant for each step of a degree equal to the order of the `NDSolve` method. For the default `LSODA`, which has a variable order, it uses either Hermite order-3 or local Taylor series. For Runge-Kutta methods, it uses Chebyshev series, which can only be used (in `InterpolatingFunction`) if the order is fixed. I left these complications out of my answer.

Comment: IIRC `Method -> "Extrapolation"` also forces `NDSolve[]` to use a Chebyshev interpolant behind the scenes.

Comment: @J.M. The method(s) used (for each step) may be inspected with `yIFN[[5]]`, but I didn't want to go through all the methods.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer @MichaelE2! This helps a ton!

Comment: @akozi You're welcome.