# Why does the domain of an interpolating function not match the corresponding ParametricNDSolve solution range?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, interpolation, simulation

### Question

I had believed - and mostly observed - that when I use `ParametricNDSolve` the obtained `ParametricFunctions` given as the solution to some ODE or DAE will be translated into `InterpolatingFunctions` that have a `Domain` that corresponds to the *solution range* of the differential (algebraic) equations.

But that does not seem to be the case. So the following questions arise:

1. Why does this happen (e.g. in which cases)?
2. What will this mean for the reliability of results?
3. In case there are negative implications, what can be done about it?

### Minimal Working Example

In the following example I have a very simple growth model for a stock, where the growth rate is a *discrete variable* that will be changed by `WhenEvents` at the times `2018, 2021, 2026`. The simulation is to run from `2016` to `2027`. In the example, I am using the options for a more elaborate simulation of a DAE.

```
parfuncs = Association @ ParametricNDSolve[
    {
        stock'[t] == stock[t] × growthRate[t],
        stock[2016] == 1,
        growthRate[2016] == gr0,
        WhenEvent[ t > 2018, growthRate[t] -> gr1],
        WhenEvent[ t > 2021, growthRate[t] -> gr2], 
        WhenEvent[ t > 2026, growthRate[t] -> gr3]  
    },
    { stock, growthRate },
    { t, 2016, 2027 },
    { gr0, gr1, gr2, gr3 },
    DiscreteVariables -> { growthRate },
    InterpolationOrder -> Automatic, (* alternatively: 1, 2, or All *)
    Method -> {
        "EquationSimplification" -> { Automatic, "SimplifySystem" -> False },
        "ParametricSensitivity" -> None,
        "IndexReduction" -> {
            "Pantelides",
            "IndexGoal" -> 1,
            "ConstraintMethod" -> Automatic
        }
    } 
];

intFunc = ReplaceAll[
    parfuncs[stock][gr0,gr1,gr2,gr3],
    {
      gr0 -> 0.01,
      gr1 -> 0.03,
      gr2 -> 0.05,
      gr3 -> 0.01
    }
]
```

> [image: InterpolatingFunction]

As we can see, the Domain is `{2020., 2030.}`. I also note, that the option `InterpolationOrder` seems to be rather irrelevant (e.g. setting it to 1 or 2 does not change anything at all, the `Order` remains to be `3`).

**Edit:**

I note, that when I shift the actual times to `0` (e.g. 2016 $\rightarrow$ 0, 2018 $\rightarrow$ 2, 2021 $\rightarrow$ 5, 2026 $\rightarrow$ 10, 
2027 $\rightarrow$ 11), the `Domain` is given correctly as `{0., 11.}`, so there may be rounding issues involved.

Checking this hunch for my MWE reveals:

```
intFunc["Domain"]
```

> {{2016., 2027.}}

So it *is* rounding and it certainly is quite confusing, as for certain parameters, the function will give a domain of `{2020.,2020.}`.

Comment: Quite interestingly this kind of `Property` investigation (e.g. "Domain") is undocumented and `Properties` of `InterpolationFunction` do not show up.

Comment: Just for completeness: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13836/764) shows, that there is really not that much use for `InterpolationOrder` in `NDSolve`, besides setting it to `All`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the formatting routine `` BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox `` for `InterpolatingFunction` sets `PrintPrecision -> 3`, so you get the domain rounded to three digits.

```
foo = parfuncs[stock][0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.01]
```

[image]

```
MakeBoxes[#, StandardForm] &@foo /. 
  HoldPattern[PrintPrecision -> 3] -> PrintPrecision -> 4 //
 RawBoxes
```

[image]

You can also somewhat guess this is the problem if you copy and paste the domain from the summary form.

Comment: Currently (V12.1.1), the print precision is hard-coded in ``ElisionsDump`makeGrid``.