# Strange plot results from NDSolve with ExplicitEuler

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

The following code attempts to plot Euler approximations to an autonomous system of ODEs of the form $x'=y$, $y'=-x$. Click at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ in the $xy$-window to generate a plot based on the `ExactEuler` method using `NDSolve` on the time interval [0,$t_f$] with step size $h$ and initial values $x(0)=x_0, y(0)=y_0$

```
Panel@DynamicModule[{g = {}, p = {}, sol, x0, y0, tf, h},
  sol[{x0_, y0_}, h_] := {x[t], y[t]} /. 
    First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == x0, 
       y[0] == y0}, {x, y}, {t, -10, 10}, 
       Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, 
       StartingStepSize -> h, MaxStepFraction -> 1];
  Column[{
    Row[{Control[{{tf, Pi, Style["tf ="]}, ImageSize -> 40}], Spacer[30], 
    Control[{{h, 1.0, Style["h ="]}, ImageSize -> 40}], Spacer[220], 
    Button[Style["Delete all solutions"], g = {}; p = {}, 
    ImageSize -> {Automatic, 25}]}],
ClickPane[
    Dynamic@Show[
    ParametricPlot[g, {t, -tf, tf}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
    PlotPoints -> Ceiling[tf/h], MaxRecursion -> 0, 
    ImageSize -> 400, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
    PlotLabel -> Dynamic[Style[MousePosition["Graphics"]]]],
    Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[p]}]],
   (AppendTo[g, sol[#, h]]; AppendTo[p, #]) &]}]]
```

The strange plots are illustrated below. Start with the upper left plot; the solution through the point $(0,0.5)$ with $h=1.0$ on the time interval $[0,2\pi]$ looks reasonable. For the upper right plot set $h=0.5$ and click on the point $(0,0.5)$ to obtain a second solution through $(0,0.5)$. Note how the first solution (with $h=1.0)$ has shifted. The lower right plot shows a third solution through $(0,0.5)$ with $h=0.25$. Note how the first two solutions morphed into new curves. The situation becomes even weirder in the lower right plot when the solution through $(0,0.5)$ with $h=0.1$ as added. Note how the polygonal form of the $h=1.0)$ solution has morphed into a smooth curve.

[image]

It gets weirder still when the plotting interval is expanded to go backward in time (by modifying the time interval for `ParametricPlot` to be $[-t_f,t_f]$. The next image shows plots of "solutions" on $[-\pi,\pi]$ with $h=1.0$ produced by random clicks in the $xy$-plane.  Notice how each solution is disjoint from it's initial point.

[image]

I suspect that the strange behavior may be result from my improper use of the `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` options for `ParametricPlot`. Although I can code the Euler method directly from its simple formula, I need to stick with the `NDSolve` method and the same `AppendTo` construction you see in my code.

I don't know how to resolve these issues.

Comment: The problem seems to be due to the fact that `NDSolve[]` is performing cubic Hermite interpolation by default. Unfortunately, even when I tried explicitly setting `InterpolationOrder -> 1` in `NDSolve[]`, I still got a cubic interpolant. Hmm...

Comment: Your second problem (the lines not going through the initial point) probably has to do with the fact that the you have evaluated each curve at an even number of points (4), but the original grid from your Euler integration used an odd number of points.  This may be one of those rare times when it is useful to reach under the hood and grab the data underlying the interpolating function that NDSolve returns.

Comment: @J.M. ["For an ODE of order $n$,...$2n+1$seems like a lower bound on the interpolation order"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13836/the-only-usage-for-the-option-interpolationorder-in-ndsolve-is-to-be-set-to-all/145853#145853) of  solution obtained from `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot just the steps, extract the [`"ValuesOnGrid"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28341/4999) from the interpolating functions and plot them with `ListLinePlot`:

```
Panel@DynamicModule[{g = {}, p = {}, sol, x0, y0, tf, h}, 
  sol[{x0_, y0_}, h_] := {x[t], y[t]} /. 
    First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == x0, 
       y[0] == y0}, {x, y}, {t, -10, 10},
      Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}, 
      StartingStepSize -> h, MaxStepFraction -> 1];
  Column[{
    Row[{
      Control[{{tf, Pi, Style["tf ="]}, ImageSize -> 40}],
      Spacer[30],
      Control[{{h, 1.0, Style["h ="]}, ImageSize -> 40}],
      Spacer[220],
      Button[
       Style["Delete all solutions"],
       g = {}; p = {},
       ImageSize -> {Automatic, 25}]}],
    ClickPane[
     Dynamic@Show[
       ListLinePlot[                                 (* replaces ParametricPlot *)
        Transpose[# /. t -> "ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ g,  (* constructs the points *)
        ImageSize -> 400, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
        AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
        PlotLabel -> Dynamic[Style[MousePosition["Graphics"]]]],
       Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[p]}],
       PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}               (* move PlotRange here *)
       ],
     (AppendTo[g, sol[#, h]]; AppendTo[p, #]) &]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As J.M. observed, the interpolating functions automatically use cubic Hermite interpolation. The adjustment of the number of points plotted with `PlotPoints -> Ceiling[tf/h]` means the number of points plotted increases as `h` decreases, if you follow the protocol in the OP.  As the number of plot points becomes much greater than the number of steps, the cubic nature of the interpolation becomes more apparent.

Comment: Your answer does not allow me to set the number of steps to use; namely Ceiling[tf/h]. The plot through any point on the time interval [0,2Pi] should approximate a circle. Perhaps I don't understand the role of ValuesOnGrid.

Comment: Michael 2E: The four plots were based on the interval {t,0,tf} and not {t,-tf,tf} as posted in my code. Sorry for any confusion this might have caused. Modifying your code to replace {t,-10,10} in `NDSolve` with {t,0,tf} appears make `ListLinePlot` generate twice as many steps.

Comment: @Stephen `PlotPoints -> Ceiling[tf/h]` does not set the number of steps in the `NDSolve` solution.  It sets the initial number of points used by `ParametricPlot`. (I don't think the points even correspond to the steps in the solutions.) Is that what you want? -- Oops, I overlooked `tf` (somehow I had thought it was the same as `10`). `ListLinePlot` just plots data, and the data used in my answer is the whole solution, not just the solution up to `tf`. Sorry about that. I might just delete this answer. I'm not sure what you want to do or why, but I can see this does not do it.

Comment: What I want is just to plot an Euler solution from t=0 to t=tf. More generally, how do I extract the appropriate `InterpolatingPoints` for `ListLinePlot`?

Comment: @Stephen, in that case, to get a picture of the piecewise linear solution, just use the `"ValuesOnGrid"` property as Michael does and feed that to `ListLinePlot[]`; no need for `ParametricPlot[]` anymore. If you want to be able to interpolate linearly as well, then you will have to use `Interpolation[]` with `InterpolationOrder -> 1` on the values obtained from `"ValuesOnGrid"`.

Comment: All is working now! :)