# Extracting the function from InterpolatingFunction object

Tags: functions, interpolation, piecewise

I've used `Interpolation[]` to generate an `InterpolatingFunction` object from a list of integers.

```
f = Interpolation[{2, 5, 9, 15, 22, 33, 50, 70, 100, 145, 200, 280, 375, 495, 635, 800,
                   1000, 1300, 1600, 2000, 2450, 3050, 3750, 4600, 5650, 6950}]
```

I'm using that to generate values like `f[27]`, `f[28]`, ...

Is there any way to print or show the function used by *Mathematica* that produced the result of `f[27]`?

Comment: You can view the internal parts of an `InterpolatingFunction` using "Methods" as I outlined here: [(19042)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19043) however that only shows the data that is used and the kind of interpolation, not the actual function itself.  You might find value in `InterpolatingPolynomial`, though it is not the same as `Interpolation`.

Comment: See [Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html#13977696) for an example; see also [Some Notes on Internal Implementation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#16712).

Comment: I am pretty sure that Mathematica uses interpolating polynomials, using [Neville's algorithm.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NevillesAlgorithm.html)
It is easy to implement this yourself and see if you get the same value.

Comment: Strongly related: [(a/154915)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154915/280).

Comment: The interpolation is a piecewise polynomial of some order (by default, 3). Are you looking for something like an explicit `Piecewise` representation?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Yes, that's what I mean. Under some condition, for example, I want to make a lagrange interpolation towards some data, and I know how to compute that by hand. Mathematica can do the same work, but it doesn't give the explicit representation.

Comment: Maybe you want `InterpolatingPolynomial` instead of `Interpolation`.

Comment: @Szabolcs it's my fault not to look up for related functions carefully…thanks for your respond.

Comment: @Szabolcs if I'm reading this right, certainly not. That one gives a polynomial of arbitrarily high degree which is probably not that useful.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Well, OP said "Lagrange interpolation" in the comment above.

Comment: @Szabolcs good point, though his answer to my question contradicts the rest of his comment.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is the example from the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html#13977696) adapted for the OP's data:

```
data = MapIndexed[
   Flatten[{#2, #1}] &,
   {2, 5, 9, 15, 22, 33, 50, 70, 100, 145, 200, 280, 375, 495, 635, 800,
    1000, 1300, 1600, 2000, 2450, 3050, 3750, 4600, 5650, 6950}];
f = Interpolation@data
```

> ```
> (* InterpolatingFunction[{{1, 26}}, <>] *)
> ```

```
pwf = Piecewise[
     Map[{InterpolatingPolynomial[#, x], x < #[[3, 1]]} &, Most[#]], 
     InterpolatingPolynomial[Last@#, x]] &@Partition[data, 4, 1];
```

Here is a comparison of the piecewise interpolating polynomials and the interpolating function:

```
Plot[f[x] - pwf, {x, 1, 28}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The values of `f[27]` and `f[28]` are beyond the domain, which is `1 <= x <= 26`, and extrapolation is used.  The formula for extrapolation is given by the last `InterpolatingPolynomial` in `pwf`:

```
Last@pwf
(* 3750 + (850 + (100 + 25/3 (-25 + x)) (-24 + x)) (-23 + x) *)
```

---

In response to a comment:  The error in the plot has to do with round-off error.  Apparently the calculation done by `InterpolatingFunction`, while algebraically equivalent, is not numerically identical.  The error was greatest above in the domain `26 < x < 28` where extrapolation is performed.  With arbitrary precision, the error is zero, as shown below.

```
Plot[f[x] - pwf, {x, 1, 28}, PlotRange -> All, 
 WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision, Exclusions -> None, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: (+1) The `data` in your answer should be defined as simple 1D list in order your code to work properly. How do you explain relatively large differences (`1*10^-12`) between your implementation and the built-in?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks.  See the update for the error explanation.  (I copied the wrong code by mistake. It should work now.)

Comment: Thanks, it is clear now. I would add that plotting *relative* error would be more correct and it clearly shows that the relative error is of expected magnitude of lesser than 10^-15: `Plot[(f[x] - pwf)/pwf, {x, 1, 28}, PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov  Good point.  I usually do consider relative error, but I was not thinking clearly and copied the code from the documentation.

Comment: Is the success of this method reliant on data points being equidistant? I tried adapting it in the [linked dupe](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/157666/26956), but clearly get invalid results.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP There is no example in the linked dupe, but, yes, the old code assumed the abscissae were successive integers.  Fixed now, I think.  Let me know if it doesn't work for you. It won't work on all `InterpolatingFunction` methods, I think, just this type.

Comment: I have fake data of the form `data = Transpose[{#, Sin[#/30] + RandomReal[.1, 35]}] &@
   Sort[RandomReal[100, 35]]` in my answer under the link. Your fixed answer now works on `{x,y}` tuples out of the box, but that was the easy part, `InterpolatingPolynomial` doesn't seem to reproduce the result of `Interpolation` for arbitrarily spaced points (not that I'm complaining :-).

Comment: @LLlAMnYP The method above does work on unequally spaced points, but not if the spacing varies wildly. It appears that `InterpolatingFunction` automatically splits `data` at points that are too close (I can get it to match if there aren't too many too-close points in a row). Or maybe it adapts the order locally. I don't know the criterion used. It is perhaps if the slope is too great in some relative sense. The result of `InterpolatingFunction` seems worse than the piecewise one in the example I got from your (random) code. Interesting -- didn't know it did such complicated things.

Answer (score 24):

There is no documented built-in way to convert the `InterpolatingFunction` object into [explicit `Piecewise` form](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html#13977696) (thanks to @MichaelE2 for the link!). So the only possibility to get an explicit interpolating function is to re-implement the built-in `Interpolation` in the high-level *Mathematica* language. I have already done this for the built-in `"Spline"` method with `InterpolationOrder -> 2` (quadratic spline interpolation with splicing points in the middle of adjacent interpolation points). Spline interpolation in general gives much better results than the default `"Hermite"` method.

You can use [my implementation of quadric spline interpolation in *Mathematica*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48133/280) to produce an explicit `Piecewise` function interpolating your data (as opposed to the built-in, it supports arbitrary precision!):

```
data = Transpose[{Range[Length[#]], #}] &@{2, 5, 9, 15, 22, 33, 50, 70, 100, 145};
spline[\[FormalX]_] = makeSpline[toSplineData[data], \[FormalX]]
```

[image: screenshot]

Here is a comparison with the original `data` and with the built-in `Interpolation`:

```
Table[data[[x, 2]] - spline[x], {x, 10}]
f = Interpolation[data, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 2];
Table[f[x] - spline[x], {x, 10}]
Plot[(f[x] - spline[x])/spline[x], {x, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> {0., 0., 0., 1.77636*10^-15, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}
> ```
>
> [image: plot]

Comment: Is it equivalent to what Mma implements for `Interpolation[pts]`?

Comment: @belisarius It is equivalent to `Interpolation[pts, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 2]` with the only difference that my implementation supports arbitrary precision while the current *Mathematica*'s built-in for `"Spline"` allows only `MachinePrecision`.

Comment: I answered the same question where you wrote that answer, but I think the OP is asking another specific thing here about the `InterpolatingFunction`oject

Comment: You know that there is no documented built-in way to convert `InterpolatingFunction` into explicit `Piecewise` form. I am sure that there is no undocumented way too because (at least `"Hermite"` method) is written in C, not in the high-level *Mathematica* language. So the only possibility to answer the question is to provide a high-level (re)implementation of the `Interpolation`.

Answer (score 18):

In M11+ you can use the "GetPolynomial" method of an interpolating function to obtain the corresponding piecewise expression (but only when using the default "Hermite" method):

```
InterpolationToPiecewise[if_, x_] := Module[{main, default, grid},
    grid = if["Grid"];
    Piecewise[
        {if @ "GetPolynomial"[#, x-#], x < First @ #}& /@ grid[[2 ;; -2]],
        if @ "GetPolynomial"[#, x-#]& @ grid[[-1]]
    ]
] /; if["InterpolationMethod"] == "Hermite"
```

For your example:

```
f = Interpolation[{2, 5, 9, 15, 22, 33, 50, 70, 100, 145, 200, 280, 375, 495, 635, 800,
               1000, 1300, 1600, 2000, 2450, 3050, 3750, 4600, 5650, 6950}];
pw = InterpolationToPiecewise[f, x];
pw //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  \left(\left(\frac{x-3}{6}+\frac{1}{2}\right) (x-1)+3\right) (x-2)+5 & x<2 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{x-4}{6}+1\right) (x-2)+4\right) (x-3)+9 & x<3 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{5-x}{6}+\frac{1}{2}\right) (x-3)+6\right) (x-4)+15 & x<4 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{x-6}{2}+2\right) (x-4)+7\right) (x-5)+22 & x<5 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{x-7}{3}+3\right) (x-5)+11\right) (x-6)+33 & x<6 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{8-x}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\right) (x-6)+17\right) (x-7)+50 & x<7 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{7 (x-9)}{6}+5\right) (x-7)+20\right) (x-8)+70 & x<8 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{5 (x-10)}{6}+\frac{15}{2}\right) (x-8)+30\right) (x-9)+100 & x<9 \\
>  \left(\left(5-\frac{5 (x-11)}{6}\right) (x-9)+45\right) (x-10)+145 & x<10 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{5 (x-12)}{2}+\frac{25}{2}\right) (x-10)+55\right) (x-11)+200 & x<11 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{15}{2}-\frac{5 (x-13)}{3}\right) (x-11)+80\right) (x-12)+280 & x<12 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{5 (x-14)}{3}+\frac{25}{2}\right) (x-12)+95\right) (x-13)+375 & x<13 \\
>  \left(\left(10-\frac{5 (x-15)}{6}\right) (x-13)+120\right) (x-14)+495 & x<14 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{5 (x-16)}{6}+\frac{25}{2}\right) (x-14)+140\right) (x-15)+635 & x<15
>    \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{5 (x-17)}{3}+\frac{35}{2}\right) (x-15)+165\right) (x-16)+800 & x<16
>    \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{65 (x-18)}{6}+50\right) (x-16)+200\right) (x-17)+1000 & x<17 \\
>  \left(300-\frac{50}{3} (x-19) (x-17)\right) (x-18)+1300 & x<18 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{50 (x-20)}{3}+50\right) (x-18)+300\right) (x-19)+1600 & x<19 \\
>  \left(\left(25-\frac{25 (x-21)}{3}\right) (x-19)+400\right) (x-20)+2000 & x<20 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{50 (x-22)}{3}+75\right) (x-20)+450\right) (x-21)+2450 & x<21 \\
>  \left(\left(50-\frac{25 (x-23)}{3}\right) (x-21)+600\right) (x-22)+3050 & x<22 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{25 (x-24)}{3}+75\right) (x-22)+700\right) (x-23)+3750 & x<23 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{25 (x-25)}{3}+100\right) (x-23)+850\right) (x-24)+4600 & x<24 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{25 (x-26)}{3}+125\right) (x-24)+1050\right) (x-25)+5650 & x<25 \\
>  \left(\left(\frac{25 (x-24)}{3}+125\right) (x-25)+1300\right) (x-26)+6950 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

Visualization:

```
Plot[
    {f[x], pw},
    {x, 1, 27},
    PlotStyle->{Directive[Thickness[.02], LightOrange], Directive[Thin, Blue]}
]
```

[image]

The error is negligible:

```
Plot[f[x]-pw, {x, 1, 27}, PlotRange->{-10^-15, 10^-15}]
```

[image]

Comment: `points = {{1, 4}, {2, 7}, {3, 2}, {4, 8}, {5, 9}};InterpolationToPiecewise[if_, x_] := 
 Module[{main, default, grid}, grid = if["Grid"];
   Piecewise[{if@"GetPolynomial"[#, x - #], x < First@#} & /@ 
     grid[[2 ;; -2]], if@"GetPolynomial"[#, x - #] &@grid[[-1]]]] /; 
  if["InterpolationMethod"] == "Hermite"
f2 = Interpolation[points, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
   Method -> "Spline"];

pw = InterpolationToPiecewise[f2, x]`
But this case with parameters can not output the desired results.

Comment: @Please, because you added `Method -> "Spline"` when Carl said that this function is only intended for `Method -> "Hermite"`.

Comment: I wonder if `x < First @ #` should be `x <= First @ #`. Then with an interpolating function of `InterpolationOrder -> 2`, the derivatives at the nodes of the interpolating function and the piecewise function with differentiated polynomials agree. It may seem a moot point, since the true derivative is undefined at the nodes in general. See this example for a case where there is computational disagreement: https://pastebin.com/Mcd8kCwz . Ref: the commentary [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/286828/286832?noredirect=1#comment714476_286832).

Answer (score 13):

You could use `Series`. What's necessary is to know which abscissa values were used for the interpolation. Let's generate some fake data.

```
xVals = RandomReal[{0, 100}, 35] // Sort;
yVals = Sin[xVals/30] + RandomReal[.1, 35];
ListPlot[{xVals, yVals}\[Transpose]]
```

> [image]

Create the interpolation:

```
iPol = Interpolation[{xVals, yVals}\[Transpose]]
```

Get the `Series` expansion at some point:

```
Series[iPol[x], {x, xVals[[5]], 4}]
```

> ```
> 0.469053+0.0487866 (x-14.3715)+0.011059 (x-14.3715)^2+0.00100578 (x-14.3715)^3+O[x-14.3715]^5
> ```

Note that there is no 4th order term (as expected, since default interpolation order is 3).

Let's generate a piecewise function:

```
pW[x_] = Piecewise[
  Table[{Normal@Series[iPol[x], {x, x0, 3}], x < x0}, {x0, xVals}]]
```

> [image]

Test it out:

```
Plot[pW[x] - iPol[x], {x, xVals[[1]], xVals[[-1]]} PlotRange->Full]
```

> [image]

Looks like (almost) machine precision to me

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's indeed a uniform way to find the explicit representation.

Comment: @user52830 You're welcome. Barring edge cases, if you happen to have just the `InterpolatingFunction` object, you can modify my `Table` statement as `Table[..., {x0, iPol[[3,1]]}]` since `iPol[[3,1]] === xVals`

Answer (score 12):

Here is a (mostly) general routine that (tries to) convert a one-dimensional `InterpolatingFunction[]` into an equivalent `Piecewise[]` function:

```
convertToPiecewise::umet = "Unknown interpolation method `1`.";
SetAttributes[convertToPiecewise, Listable];

convertToPiecewise[iF_InterpolatingFunction, x_,
                   OptionsPattern[{"Extrapolation" -> False,
                                   InterpolationOrder -> Automatic}]] := 
       Module[{bf, extQ, imet, kp, makePP, met, nodes, perQ, pieces, pts, vand, xt},
              Switch[met = iF["InterpolationMethod"],
                     "Hermite" | "Chebyshev",
                     pts = Transpose[{Flatten[iF["Grid"]], iF["ValuesOnGrid"]}],
                     "BSpline",
                     bf = First[Cases[iF, _BSplineFunction, ∞]];
                     pts = {#, bf[#]} & /@ Union[First[bf["Knots"]]],
                     _,
                     Message[convertToPiecewise::umet, met]; Return[$Failed, Module]];
              kp = OptionValue[InterpolationOrder];
              If[kp === Automatic,
                 (* repeated differentiation to determine maximal order *)
                 kp = If[met =!= "BSpline",
                         First[NestWhile[Derivative[1],
                                         Derivative[First[iF["InterpolationOrder"]] +
                                                    1][iF],
                                         (Norm[#["ValuesOnGrid"], ∞] > 0) &]
                               ["DerivativeOrder"]] - 1,
                 kp = First[bf["Degree"]]]];
              If[kp > 0, (* normal case *)
                 (* use equispaced nodes in the exact case, and Chebyshev otherwise *)
                 nodes = Range[kp - 1]/kp;
                 If[MatrixQ[pts, InexactNumberQ],
                    nodes = N[Haversine[π nodes], Precision[pts]]];
                 vand = LinearAlgebra`Private`VandermondeSolve[##, Transpose -> True] &;
                 makePP[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] := Module[{h = x2 - x1, ip},
                     ip = Transpose[Join[{{x1 - x1, y1}},
                                         {#, iF[x1 + #]} & /@ (h nodes), {{h, y2}}]];
                     (* solve for interpolating polynomial coefficients *)
                     {Fold[(#1 (xt - x1) + #2) &, Reverse[vand @@ ip]], x1 <= xt <= x2}];
                 pieces = makePP /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1],
                 (* zero-order interpolation *)
                 pieces = Transpose[{Rest[pts[[All, -1]]],
                                     #1 <= xt <= #2 & @@@
                                     Partition[pts[[All, 1]], 2, 1]}]];
              perQ = TrueQ[First[iF["Periodicity"]]];
              If[! perQ, extQ = OptionValue["Extrapolation"];
                 If[! ListQ[extQ], extQ = {extQ, extQ}]; extQ = TrueQ /@ extQ;
                 If[extQ[[1]], pieces[[1, 2]] = Delete[pieces[[1, 2]], 1]];
                 If[extQ[[2]], pieces[[-1, 2]] = Delete[pieces[[-1, 2]], 3]]];
                 Piecewise[pieces /. xt ->
                           If[! perQ, x, Mod[x, #2 - #1, #1] & @@ First[iF["Domain"]]]]]
```

(N.B. replace `` LinearAlgebra`Private`VandermondeSolve[] `` with `` LinearAlgebra`VandermondeSolve[] `` when using the function in versions before 11.2.)

It should work for `InterpolatingFunction[]` objects that come from `Interpolation[]`, `ListInterpolation[]`, or `FunctionInterpolation[]`. It mostly works for `InterpolatingFunction[]` objects from `NDSolve[]`, but may fail in some cases. (If you find an example, please tell me!)

Some examples:

```
if1 = Interpolation[{1, 3, 5, 2, 1}, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

Here, we tell `convertToPiecewise[]` to use the rightmost piece for extrapolation to the right:

```
convertToPiecewise[if1, x, "Extrapolation" -> {False, True}]
```

$$\begin{cases}
 2 (x-1)+1 & 1\leq x\leq 2 \\
 2 (x-2)+3 & 2\leq x\leq 3 \\
 5-3 (x-3) & 3\leq x\leq 4 \\
 6-x & 4\leq x \\
0 & \mathtt{True}
\end{cases}$$

Convert an `InterpolatingFunction[]` with irregular spacing:

```
if2 = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {0.1, .3}, {0.5, .6}, {1, -.2}, {2, 3}}, Method -> "Spline"];

pw2[x_] = convertToPiecewise[if2, x];

Plot[if4[x] - pw4[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: spline interpolant error]

Convert the result of `NDSolve[]`:

```
if3 = NDSolveValue[{g'[x] == Sin[2 x] - g[x], g[0] == 1}, g, {x, 0, 6}];

pw3[x_] = convertToPiecewise[if3, x];

Plot[if3[x] - pw3[x], {x, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: error of interpolant from NDSolve]

Another `NDSolve[]` example. The previous version of the routine was unable to handle this.

```
if4 = NDSolveValue[{y''[t] == 10 (1 - y[t]^2) y[t] - y[t], y[0] == 2, y'[0] == 0},
                   y, {t, 0, 6}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];

pw4[x_] = convertToPiecewise[if4, x];

Plot[if4[x] - pw4[x], {x, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: error of interpolant from NDSolve, second order]

Comment: I seem to have to use ``LinearAlgebra`Private`VandermondeSolve``; I can't get ``LinearAlgebra`VandermondeSolve`` to evaluate on anything.  (V11.2, Mac).

Comment: Ah, you're right, I was doing this in 11.1. I'll add a note...

Comment: Within Mathematica 12.1 your implementation seems to break for the "Splines" method. Executing your example if2 yields an "First: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[0]." error. It seems your determination of the InterpolationOrder->Automatic setting does not work anymore. If one specifies InterpolationOrder->3 explicitly to convertToPiecewise, the error goes away...

Comment: I fixed the code above to cover "Automatic" setting of the "InterpolationOrder" option. Whereas methods "Hermite" and "Chebyshev" work with the repeated differentiation to determine the maximal order of the Interpolation, this order can be determined via ```First[bf@"Degree"]``` for the "BSpline" option easily.....

Comment: @Rainer, that does seem to fix it for 12.2; thank you!

Comment: `VandermondeSolve` changes again (in _v13.0_ or _v13.1_, I'm not sure). Now it doesn't have the option `Transpose`. (BTW this breaks [`ResourceFunction["InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise/)…) Any quick fix? I just posted a new question for this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/271749/1871

Comment: @xzczd, I'll look into it sometime this week; that one was on my list of things to fix for the new version.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of trying to come up with a function that replicates the output of the [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction), one could instead "inactivate" it, and then see what kind of arithmetic it does. For instance:

```
inactiveIF = MapAt[HoldForm, f, {-2, All, 1}];
```

For example:

```
r = inactiveIF[10.5]
```

> 200-0.5 (-1. (145-200)+0.5 (1. (1. (145-200)+0.5 (-145+280))+0.75 (-1. (-0.333333 (100-280)-0.5 (-145+280))-1. (1. (145-200)+0.5 (-145+280)))))

There are hidden [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm) wrappers in the above code. If we use [`ReleaseHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold) on `r` we get the same value as using `f` directly:

```
ReleaseHold[r]
f[10.5]
```

> 170.313
>
> 170.313

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at

```
?Interpolation
```

There is a list of options. One of them is Method. Since the documentation on Interpolation as elsewhere in the Mathematica documentation is very sparse. So no overview over methods is provided. There are given two methods:

1. Spline
2. Hermite

but that is not all. The more valuable approach for insight is

```
f["Methods"]
```

or

```
f["MethodInformation"@#] &~Scan~f["Methods"]
```

as mentioned in a post above. From the increase in lack of information in

```
InterpolatingFunction
```

it can be assumed that `InterpolationFunction` is close related to `Interpolation`.

So You have to use the documentation against intuitivity.

Nice example for further reach to exactness is `InterpolationOrder` and the reverse naming `FunctionInterpolation`, with is simply the job for calculating an interpolation representation for an mathematical given function.

This shows up a somehow sophistication perspective on the given question. For computation there is no need for that. In contrary Mathematica internally represents even the nicest solution given here again as an InterpolatingFunction.

The options `InterpolationOrder` and `PeriodicInterpolation` drive the problem even deeper. Because instead of making the Taylor approximation exact over the interval of representation, the use of the infinite approximation is needed. Not only polynomials are use but trigonometrical functions and other classes of functions usable for function representation.

Beyond that the Mathematica documentation offers an example in the page for `ListInterpolation` in the section possible issues:

"Beyond the domain defined by the original data extrapolation is used:

```
f = ListInterpolation[Table[Sin[2 Pi x], {x, 0, 1, .1}], {{0, 1}}]
```

[image: Screencopy of Mathematica Documentation for ListInterpolations]

This question targets some aspects not considered inside the domain of the function implemented. I read the example as double outside of domain. One is the interval domain and the other a mathematical function, a periodic and transcendent one, is first discretized, then interpolated to evaluation purposes and then used avoiding the direct path and calculation Sin[3 Pi]. The chosen process induces possible error.

Somehow the built-in symbol [`Fit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html) solves this domain much more in the univariate domain. For a polynomial of order three the result is the same as with `InterpolatingFunction` in this case.

```
ffit = Fit[{2, 5, 9, 15, 22, 33, 50, 70, 100, 145, 200, 280, 375, 495,
    635, 800, 1000, 1300, 1600, 2000, 2450, 3050, 3750, 4600, 5650, 
   6950}, {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x]
```

(* -338.485 + 194.733 x - 25.6637 x^2 + 1.0972 x^3 *).

No piecewise, no trick needed. Keep in mind that the `{1, x, x^2, x^3}` is the basis in which the data is represented. The use of another basis gives a different result. Example for such basises are Splines, Hermite Polynomials, trigonometric functions and else univariate functional representation even InterpolatingFunctions are possible. As in multidimensional spaces the dimensions have to be matched to the given data. To many data that is not independent can flaw the result and cause to much work. So check your data before fitting or interpolating and do this than lacy and most accurate.

The instruction

```
f["MethodInformation"@GetPolynomial]
```

(* InterpolatingFunction[domain, data]@GetPolynomial[p, s] gives the polyomial used around p for symbolic s *)

should do the trick on the other side of possible interpretation.

In the built-in symbol FindRoots there is an rather attractive method, option `Exclusions`. Mathematica makes it possible to define basises with this special extra wish.

Comment: It isn't clear what parts of this answer are relevant to the question.

Comment: This answer anticipated the `Hermite` is the method option suitable only. It points to `GetPolynomial` is an more instructive manner than the answer selected for the bounty. You are not restricted to Piecewise, just splice the `InterpolatingFunctions` approriate: [splice together](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/how-to-splice-together-several-instances-of-interpolatingfunction)