# Show actual Interpolation function

Tags: interpolation

Is there a command to show the actual function when using the Interpolation command?

For example, f = Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}] returns

```
             InterpolatingFunction[{{1, 6}}, <>]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59944/134).

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(19042)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19042/121), 
[(59944)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59944/121)