# Hermite method in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

When I solve the example below, in the results it is mentioned that *Mathematica* 10 has used the Hermite method. I cannot find anything about this in the *Mathematica* documentation.
Is there nothing about the Hermite method because it is a default method?!

```
 s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried ?[`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html) In the Details and Options section there are two pages discussing options...

Comment: @chris I couldn't find Hermite method. I changed the title of question.

Comment: It's discussed here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveEventLocator.html

Comment: Possibly relevant: "[Extracting the function from `InterpolatingFunction` object](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59944/280)."

Comment: Where in the result is Hermite mentioned?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I put the picture in the question.

Comment: A misunderstanding here, I think. The Hermite method is what the InterpolatingFunction is using (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation)), not the method used by NDSolve.

Comment: Thanks for the picture, that explains things. What @SimonWoods states is correct: the interpolating function is produced by Hermite method (as opposed to splines). The NDSolve itself is done by its own methods unrelated to the interpolation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To settle this: the "Method" in the output you've seen refers to the method used by `InterpolatingFunction[]` for interpolating between the points produced by `NDSolve[]`, not the method used by `NDSolve[]` proper. (What methods are used by `NDSolve[]` is [a whole 'nother matter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html).)

In this case, since `NDSolve[]` is perfectly capable of generating function values (from the integration method used) and derivative values (from the initial conditions and the DE itself) as it chugs along, the choice of `InterpolatingFunction[]` to use [Hermite interpolation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitesInterpolatingPolynomial.html), which is a (piecewise) interpolating polynomial built from both function and derivative values, is quite appropriate. This is the concept of ["dense output"](http://books.google.com/books?id=F93u7VcSRyYC&pg=PA188): producing a function that approximately solves a differential equation, instead of producing a table of values of the solution.