# How does Mathematica interpolates?

Tags: interpolation

In manual for [`Interpolate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) function it is said, that possible method of interpolation is `Hermite`.

Unfortunately, I can't see coincidence with Wikipedia article, where it is said that Hermite spline can be written as follows:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Mathematica file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1jZw9H7L4gmc0hDam5rTVk0VUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Shouldn't `Hermite` be `"Hermite"`?

Comment: @Öskå the same result

Comment: Strongly related: "[Extracting the function from InterpolatingFunction object](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59963/280)." MichaelE2's answer shows how the `"Hermite"` method is implemented.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov don't see how to extract function

Comment: While this question is not a duplicate I believe "(it) already has an answer here" *does* apply so I am joining belisarius in voting to close.  If anyone feels this question is not adequately addressed there please let me know.