# How to calculate the control points of a Bézier curve?

Tags: plotting, interpolation, splines

To plot a `BezierCurve` in *Mathematica*, I need control points. But, I do not know the control points; I only know the points through which the Bézier curve passes. Take a simple example:

> A Bézier curve goes through the 4 points (0,0), (2,1), (4,3) and (6,1). Find the two control points.

How would I go about finding the two control points in this example? The solution of this simple example will give me a clue on how to solve the general case.

Comment: Why do you insist on `BezierCurve` instead of `Interpolation`?

Comment: What is your code? Because `BezierCurve[pts]` doesn't go *through* these four points.

Comment: Because what I really want to do is to draw a Bezier curve containing hundred of points. I know the points that the curve passes through but in order to plot it I need the control points instead. If I can do it for a simple case of 4 points I will figure out how to do it for hundred of points.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is my approach:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {4, 3}, {6, 1}};
paras = FoldList[Plus, 0, Normalize[(Norm /@ Differences[pts]), Total]] // N
mat = Outer[BernsteinBasis[3, #1, #2] &, Range[0, 3], paras] // Transpose;
ctrlpts = LinearSolve[mat, pts]
(* {{0., 0.}, {2.71043, -0.262717}, {3.94236, 6.32778}, {6., 1.}} *)

Graphics[{BezierCurve[ctrlpts], PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[pts]}]
```

[image: Bézier]

#### Comparison with `Interpolation[]`

To show that the results of the Bézier curve interpolant and the *built-in* `Interpolation[]` are vastly different, I will use the following data:

```
pts1 = {{-1, 0}, {2, 1}, {4, 4}, {6, -3}};
mat1 = Outer[BernsteinBasis[3, #1, #2] &, Range[0, 3], 
             FoldList[Plus, 0.0, 
                      Normalize[(Norm /@ Differences[pts1]), Total]]] // Transpose;

f = Interpolation[pts1];
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 6}], 
     Graphics[{BezierCurve[LinearSolve[mat1, pts1]], 
               PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[pts1]}], 
     PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-3, 6}}]
```

[image: comparison]

Comment: Is the slight difference with `Interpolation[]` expected?

Comment: Well that's what I plotted too, I just wondered if that was expected to happen.

Comment: @Feyre Of course, they use the different algorithms(basis function). I think the `Interpolation[]` uses the classical **Largrange interpolation** strategy,  while for the Bezier curve, it uses the **Bernstein basis**.

Comment: I'm sure you could find an example where the `Interpolation` result is vastly different.  It might be worthwhile to show the comparison in the answer.

Comment: The difference is only because you used chord length instead of the abscissas in setting up the linear system for the control points.

Comment: @J.M. is right : the visual difference between the 2 curves disappears when one replace `FoldList[balh blah blah ...]` by `Rescale[First /@ pts1]` in the code above. Nevertheless it is possible that the curves are *mathematically* different, for example because the default method used by `Interpolation` is "Hermite" instead of "Spline".

Comment: @andre, in this specific case, the equivalence is clear, because there is a unique cubic polynomial that passes through four points. Thus, there should be a mapping between the Bézier version and the `Interpolation[]` version. For more than four points, what you have said is generally correct.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to resort to chord length parametrization as was done in the other answer for this simple interpolation problem.

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {4, 3}, {6, 1}};
{xt, yt} = Transpose[pts];
cp = LinearSolve[Outer[BernsteinBasis[3, #2, #1] &, Rescale[xt], Range[0, 3]], yt]
   {0, -7/6, 20/3, 1}

Graphics[{{Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], ColorData[97, 1]], 
           BezierCurve[Transpose[{xt, cp}]]},
          {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[6], ColorData[97, 2]], Point[pts]}}]
```

[image: interpolating Bézier curve]

An explanation for the following two results is left as an exercise for the interested reader:

```
if = Interpolation[pts];
Plot[if[x], {x, 0, 6}, 
     Epilog -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], ColorData[97, 2]],
                BezierCurve[Transpose[{xt, cp}]]}, 
     PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[6]]
```

[image: BezierCurve vs. InterpolatingFunction]

```
Plot[if[x] - cp.BernsteinBasis[3, Range[0, 3], Rescale[x, MinMax[xt]]],
     {x, 0, 6}, Evaluated -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: difference]