# Find interpolation with derivatives at some points

Tags: fitting, interpolation

I am trying to find out how to find a good interpolation of a **periodic function** I have from some data points.

The only problem is that I need to make sure that **derivatives** at the starting and ending points are fixed (not at every point), the function must be constrained **between 0 and 1**, and of course, smooth.

For a better explanation of my objective, here's a picture, where the red additions are mine to show how interpolation should behave:

[image: target]

```
data = {{0, 0}, {1.1, 0.8}, {1.4, 1}, {1.7, 0.8}, {2.6, 0.2}, {3.6, 
   0.06}, {5, 0}}

g[t_] := Interpolation[data, t]
Show[
 Plot[g[t], {t, 0, 5}],
 ListPlot[data]
 ]
```

All my attempts with `Fit`, `Interpolation`, and [Bezier](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125583/how-to-calculate-the-control-points-of-a-b%C3%A9zier-curve/125584) curves failed.

Any hints?

Comment: What is periodic about your function?

Comment: Unless you can get more data points, what about `g[t_] := Interpolation[data, t, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
  Method -> "Spline"]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {{0, 0}, {1.1, 0.8}, {1.4, 1}, {1.7, 0.8}, {2.6, 0.2}, {3.6, 0.06}, {5, 0}};
```

Set the derivative to zero for first point, last point, and peak point.

```
data2 = ({{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]} & /@ 
    data) /. {{x_?(# == Min[data[[All, 1]]] || # == Max[data[[All, 1]]] || # ==
           data[[Position[data[[All, 2]], Max[data[[All, 2]]]][[1, 1]], 
            1]] &)}, v_} :> {{x}, v, 0}

(* {{{0}, 0, 0}, {{1.1}, 0.8}, {{1.4}, 1, 0}, {{1.7}, 0.8}, {{2.6}, 0.2}, 
   {{3.6}, 0.06}, {{5}, 0, 0}} *)
```

Interpolating the revised data

```
f = Interpolation[data2, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

Checking the derivatives

```
f' /@ {0, 1.4, 5}

(* {-1.11022*10^-16, 0., 0.} *)
```

Plotting

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[data]}]
```

[image]

Since the derivative is not known for all points, much of the plot is only piecewise continuous.

Comment: Wonderful! I just have one question that completes my doubts. Is it possible in Mathematica to interpolate as you did, but leaving *some points* unconstrained? For instance the fifth point, or third and sixth? Of course it would be a best fit and not what I was looking for, but it’s interesting nonetheless.

Comment: If `f1` is the interpolated function and `f2` is a fitted function, then `f3[x_] = w*f1[x] + (1-w)*f2[x]` with `0 < w < 1` would give you a weighted mixture.

Comment: You might want to look at this solution https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/218764/1089