# Derivative of Interpolation parameters

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, interpolation

I am working with interpolation function with some non-numerical arguments. A simplified version of the function I am working with is:

```
FUNC = Interpolation[{{0, a}, {1, b}, {2, c}}]
```

I would like to compute the derivative of FUNC with respect to a, b and c (for a general function value)

Potential solution: obtain the piecewise function that Interpolation generates. Problem: I do not know how to extract this piecewise function from FUNC.

Comment: Is not it the same as computing a derivative of the interpolating function?

Comment: No. Typically, the derivative would be FUNC'[x]. However, I do not want dFUNC/dx, but dFUNC/da, where a is one of the parameters specified above.

Comment: The piecewise function that the interpolating function represents depends on the interpolation method and the data.  Here is one way: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59963/4999

Comment: This makes no sense because this derivative is not defined by your data unless it contains `{0,a}` and `{0,a+some value}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[a_, b_, c_] = Interpolation[
   {{0, a}, {1, b}, {2, c}},
   InterpolationOrder -> 2];

xValues = Range[0, 2, 1/8];

fValues = f[a, b, c] /@ xValues // Simplify;

dfda[x_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[
   {xValues, D[#, a] & /@ fValues} // Transpose, x] //
  Simplify

(*  1/2 (2 - 3 x + x^2)  *)

Plot[dfda[x], {x, 0, 2},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {"x", "df / da"})]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** As [Breugem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9190/breugem) suggested in his comment to this answer, working directly with the [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html) is more straightforward.

```
fp[a_, b_, c_, x_] = 
 InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, a}, {1, b}, {2, c}}, x] // Simplify

(*  a + (-a + b + 1/2 (a - 2 b + c) (-1 + x)) x  *)

D[fp[a, b, c, x], a] // Simplify

(*  1/2 (2 - 3 x + x^2)  *)
```

Comment: This is very good! The interpolating polynomial will become complex for large grids, in which a piecewise polynomial needs to be estimated, which brings us back to the original problem. I guess the most efficient way would be to generate an interpolating polynomial from the start

Comment: @Breugem Using an interpolating polynomial on more than a few points is usually a bad idea, unless your data is exact and you know a polynomial is an appropriate model.  Piecewise interpolation is usually more appropriate.

Comment: I agree:) This was my (potentially unclear) comment (i.e., we cannot use the  InterpolatingPolynomial from the answer above)