# Dealing with InterpolatingFunction in Compile

Tags: interpolation, compile

I have rather large equations that profit a lot from compiling, unfortunately they require input from external numerics and need to be interpolated.

In the end this costs a lot of performance as `InterpolatingFunction` triggers a `MainEvaluate`.

A minimal example:

```
testInt = Interpolation[{{0., 0.}, {2.5, 2.5}, {5., 5.}, {10., 10.}, {15., 
 15.}}];

testCompile = With[{testInt = testInt},
Compile[{{x, _Real}, {a, _Real}},
testInt[a*x], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
"RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed", 
CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
  "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, 
RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> False
]];

CompilePrint[testCompile]

Out[3]= "
    2 arguments
    4 Real registers
    Underflow checking off
    Overflow checking off
    Integer overflow checking off
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}

    R0 = A1
    R1 = A2
    Result = R3

1   R2 = R1 * R0
2   R3 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 15.}}, <>]][ R2]]
3   Return
"
```

The options are set as in the case of my application.

Is there any way to access circumvent this the non compilabilty of `InterpolatingFunction` by accessing for example the resulting piece wise polynomial?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59944/extracting-the-function-from-interpolatingfunction-object/59963#59963)?  Of course there are other methods of interpolation that `InterpolatingFunction` supports.

Comment: Possibly you could rearrange your code such that all interpolation is done before passing that result as a packed array to the compiled function?

Comment: @MichaelE2 sort of, it would boil down to writing my own compiled interpolation, which i will probably end up with.

Comment: @user21 I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Are all interpolation points know ahead of time?

Comment: Yes, to be more specific the data/interpolation serves as an input for solving a differential equation and is only loaded once in the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using existing code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59944/extracting-the-function-from-interpolatingfunction-object/59963#59963) to extract the piece-wise polynomial from the interpolation and compile it.

```
data = MapIndexed[
  Flatten[{#2, #1}] &, {2, 5, 9, 15, 22, 33, 50, 70, 100, 145, 200, 280, 375, 495, 635, 800, 1000, 1300, 1600, 2000, 2450, 3050, 3750, 4600, 5650, 6950}];

intF = Interpolation@data;
pwF[x_] = Piecewise[MapIndexed[{InterpolatingPolynomial[#1, x], x < 1 First[#2] + 2} &, Most[#]], InterpolatingPolynomial[Last@#1, x]] &@Partition[data, 4, 1];
compF = With[{}, Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Evaluate[N[pwf[x]]], CompilationTarget -> "C", "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]];

compF[1.]//AbsoluteTiming
pwF[1.]//AbsoluteTiming
intF[1.]//AbsoluteTiming
 {7.38984*10^-6,2.}
 {0.0000640453,2.}
 {0.0000225801,2.}
```

This solves the problem at hand and even speeds up the evaluation.

Comment: Unfortunately, at least for me in 11.2, `CompilePrint` shows this too is bailing out to `MainEvaluate`

Comment: @b3m2a1 `wF = Which @@ 
   Flatten[List[
       MapIndexed[{x < 1 First[#2] + 2, 
          InterpolatingPolynomial[#1, x]} &, Most[#]], {True, 
        InterpolatingPolynomial[Last@#1, x]}] &@
     Partition[data, 4, 1]];`  then `compF = With[{wF = wF}, 
  Compile[{{x, _Real}}, wF, CompilationTarget -> "WVM", 
   "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]]`