# Speed up numerical evaluation of extremely large expression

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, numerics

I have a large 4x4 symbolic matrix whose components are scalar functions with arguments (t,r,$\theta$, $\phi$) and various parameters. The `LeafCount` of the purely symbolic expression is around 500,000 and, after plugging in the values of the parameters, it takes 0.3 seconds to evaluate the matrix on a single co-ord point. The problem is, this function needs to be numerically integrated, so 0.3 seconds for a single point is far too slow. I've simplified all the expression that enter into the derivation of the full symbolic matrix, however executing `Simplify` or `Together` on the symbolic matrix itself crashes the kernel (it runs out of memory on my 10Gb-of-ram machine).

Unfortunately, compilation to `C` or `WVM` is not feasible since the matrix contains `InterpolatingFunctions`. I've tried implementing [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140485/dealing-with-interpolatingfunction-in-compile) solution to extract the piecewise polynomial from the InterpolatingFunction, but when trying to compile to `C`, the kernel crashes from memory usage and when compiling to `WVM`, the evaluation on a co-ordinate point fails with code

`CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.`

For clarity, I'm compiling the function only after inserting the parameter values so its only a function of (t,r,$\theta$, $\phi$), which are the arguments for the `Compile` function.

The code that generates this expression is far too long to upload, so I exported it to a `.mx` file, which can be found [here](https://github.com/Shaun-F/Tmp/blob/main/EnergyMomentumUU.mx). The parameters are (`\[chi]`, `m`, `n`, `\[omega]`, `\[nu]`) and the arguments are `(t,r, \[theta], \[phi])`. There are functions `S[\[theta]]` and `R[r[\chi]]` and their derivatives within the symbolic expression. Numerical evaluation of the expression can be done using

```
tmp[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]] /. S -> Function[{\[Theta]}, 1] /. 
          R -> Function[{r}, 1] /. \[Omega] -> 1 /. \[Nu] -> 
         1 /. \[Chi] -> 0.5 /. m -> 1 /. n -> 1 /. t -> 0 /. 
   r -> 2 /. \[Theta] -> 1 /. \[Phi] -> 0
```

for a quick output.

How then can I speed up the numerical evaluation of such a large expression? Is simplification the best route or somehow compiling to `WVM` or `C`? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can think of two things, [`OptimizeExpression`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Experimental++OptimizeExpression) and passing the interpolating function values as arguments to the compiled function.

Comment: Indeed, I tried to load the matrix into the symbol `A`. Then ``LeafCount[Experimental`OptimizeExpression[A]]`` is only $3655$ instead of $581590$. That tells me that you were quite a bit careless in generating this expression.

Comment: Thats quite surprising how much it simplifies. The quantity is the result of many tensor contractions in a kerr spacetime, so I would normally expect quite a huge expression, but it seems Mathematica is able to reduce it quite a bit. How would I convert the result from ```Experimental`OptimizeExpression``` into a function I can then numerically evaluate? Such as, inserting the parameter values and having a function like ```Function[{t,r,theta,phi}, result]``` with which I can evaluate over a co-ordinate grid?

Comment: One idea may be found in `hf1` in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240308/4999): ``myfunc = Experimental`OptimizeExpression[expr] /. 
 Experimental`OptimizedExpression[f_] :> 
  Function @@ Hold[{...args...}, f]``