# Multiply interpolating function with variable

Tags: function-construction, interpolation

I am always running into trouble when trying to use interpolating functions. I am trying to do:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ifun = ListInterpolation[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}];
mytest = Function[#1*Derivative[1, 0][ifun][#1, #2] ];
Integrate[mytest[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

But integrate doesn't evaluate. However

```
Integrate[ifun[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
mytest[1, 1]
```

works just fine. I also tried

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ifun = ListInterpolation[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}];
mytest2[x_, y_] := Evaluate[x*D[ifun[x, y], {x, 1}]]
Integrate[mytest2[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

But that didn't work either (integrate doesn't evaluate). I really don't understand what I am doing...

Comment: `NIntegrate` works.

Comment: Yes but it if the interpolating function is more complex I get a lot of warnings about slow convergence, oscillatory integrals, etc. The Random Real above is just an example. In principle Interpolating function is just a polynomial, isn't it? So one should be able to multiply it with another polynomial and integrate it exactly, or am I wrong?

Comment: You are right it is possible in principle, but is seems `Integrate` doesnt know how to do it. You might find this useful. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59944/2079

Comment: Use `FunctionInterpolation` to create `mytest`, then you can integrate that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of `FunctionInterpolation`s main purposes is to combine different expressions involving `InterpolatingFunction`s; from the docs:

> You can use FunctionInterpolation to generate a single InterpolatingFunction object from an expression containing several such objects.

In this case we can do:

```
SeedRandom[0];
ifun = ListInterpolation[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}];
deriv = Derivative[1, 0][ifun];
combined = FunctionInterpolation[x*deriv[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}];
Integrate[combined[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

> -0.00824225