# Cross product of two vector functions

Tags: interpolation, vector-calculus

I have two vector functions

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := {x, y, z}
g[x_, y_, z_] := {y, 10, x}
```

I want to take the cross product of these two vectors at every point. This should result in another vector function.

How would I do so without creating a loop using `Cross`? This seems inefficient.

Edit:

The question was in regard to interpolation functions. The method suggested in the comments does not work

```
(*create data to interpolate*)
(*each corressponds to the values in \
that direction for each function *)  
fx = Table[1, 1000];
fx = ArrayReshape[fx, {10, 10, 10}];
fy = Table[1, 1000];
fy = ArrayReshape[fy, {10, 10, 10}];
fz = Table[1, 1000];
fz = ArrayReshape[fz, {10, 10, 10}];
gx = Table[-1, 1000];
gx = ArrayReshape[gx, {10, 10, 10}];
gy = Table[-1, 1000];
gy = ArrayReshape[gy, {10, 10, 10}];
gz = Table[-1, 1000];
gz = ArrayReshape[gz, {10, 10, 10}];


(*interpolate to get vector interpolation function *) 
iff = ListInterpolation /@ {fx, fy, fz};
ifg = ListInterpolation /@ {gx, gy, gz};

gif[x_, y_, z_] := (#[x, y, z] & /@ ifg) ;
fif[x_, y_, z_] := (#[x, y, z] & /@ iff) ;

VectorPlot3D[{gif[x, y, z], fif[x, y, z]}, {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}, {z,
   1, 10}]

(*this does not work *) 
f[x,y,z]\[Cross]g[x,y,z] (*credit to kglr*)
```

I would like the cross produce between f & g.

Comment: `f[x, y, z]\[Cross]g[x, y, z]`  or `Cross @@ Through[{f, g}@##] &[x, y, z]`?

Comment: This works for the example I gave. The issue is I have a 3D interpolation function. The same method does not work. I will edit the equation to reflect this and give a MWE. My mistake. Apologies.

Comment: did you try `fif[x,y,z] \[Cross] gif[x,y,z]`?

Comment: @kglr's method `Cross[gif[x, y, z], fif[x, y, z]]` works perfectly more me. Just like `cross[]` in Marius' answer.

Comment: I did try last night, however, I must've made an error. Both methods work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote about in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143520/multiply-interpolating-function-with-variable/143582#143582) answer, the normal way to combine `InterpolatingFunction`s is to use `FunctionInterpolation`. But before I show how to do this, let me try to rephrase the `InterpolatingFunction`s you have used.

What you want from your example is one constant vector field $$\mathbf{f}(x,y,z) = (1,1,1)$$ and another constant vector field $$\mathbf{g}(x,y,z) = (-1,-1,-1)$$ if I understand correctly. The way I think one should do that is

```
coordinatePoints = Tuples[Range[1, 10], 3];
fInterpol = Interpolation[Tuples[{coordinatePoints, {{1, 1, 1}}}]];
gInterpol = Interpolation[Tuples[{coordinatePoints, {{-1, -1, -1}}}]];
```

Now these are `InterpolatingFunctions` that have **vectors as output**, e.g.

```
fInterpol[1,2,3]
```

> {1,1,1}

as you can see when you define them:

[image: f definition]

Now, I could actually *not* get *Mathematica* 10.0.2 to make an `InterpolatingFunction` out of the cross product like I usually would, because it does not seem to support vector output; I get error messages when I try to do

```
crossFailed = FunctionInterpolation[fInterpol[x, y, z]~Cross~gInterpol[x, y, z], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}, {z, 1, 10}]
```

But of course this is not needed: you can simply do:

```
cross[x_, y_, z_] := fInterpol[x, y, z]~Cross~gInterpol[x, y, z]
```

However, unless we choose some other values for $\mathbf{f}$ and/or $\mathbf{g}$, the result is always `{0,0,0}` :p

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x, y, z]\[Cross]g[x, y, z]
```

> `{x y - 10 z, -x^2 + y z, 10 x - y^2}`

or

```
Cross @@ Through[{f, g}@##] &[x, y, z]
```

> `{x y - 10 z, -x^2 + y z, 10 x - y^2}`