# Can Mathematica give the explicit expression of InterpolatingFunction?

Tags: interpolation, expression-manipulation

As we know, using the function Interpolation[], it will generate an object named InterpolatingFunction, so we can get the derivative, the graphic of the function. But sometimes we need the explicit expression of the interpolating function,  is there any way to do that?