# Obtaining the equation type of an interpolated function

Tags: functions, interpolation

I used InterpolatingFunction on a set of points.

How can I know the type of that equation ? (polynomial, sinusoidal, logarithmic,etc...). I am looking for a general case answer.

Here is an example of dataset (among others, not necessarely of the same shape):

```
{-0.21970434400207, -0.22136596455224, -0.22074715867415, -0.21931620134959, -0.21774957192979, -0.21641976791018,-0.21554440918856, -0.21524028316217}
```

Comment: Could you use `FindFormula` on the discrete data?

Comment: While FindFormula is indeed working for the simplest cases, it often breaks down for complicated functions.

Comment: I imagine it's a tricky problem in general.  Could you post some data sets that cause problems?

Comment: I just edited my question by giving an exemple. Hopefully this is a good one. For me the formula breaks down at the minima.

Comment: Unfortunately, [`PiecewiseExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html) does not work on [`InterpolatingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) objects, even though that should be a straightforward case. Has anyone found a workaround for this lack of functionality?

Comment: If by "that equation" you mean the `InterpolatingFunction`, then the `InterpolatingFunction` does piecewise polynomial interpolation, cubic by default.  See [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59963/4999), for instance.