# How to use an InterpolatingFunction inside CreateSystemModel?

Tags: differential-equations, system-modeler

I would like to to construct an equation with `CreateSystemModel`, e.g. $\dot{y}(t) = f(x(t))$, where $f$ is an interpolated function. I tried the following code

```
With[{f = Interpolation[Transpose[{Range[0, 100], Table[RandomReal[], 101]}]]}, 
 CreateSystemModel[{f[x[tau]] == y'[tau]}, 
  tau, {x \[Element] "RealInput", y \[Element] "RealOutput"}]]
```

This returns the error message `CreateSystemModel::nosup: "Found unsupported expression: \!\(\*RowBox[{RowBox[{\"<<\", \"1\", \">>\"}], \"[\", RowBox[{\"x\", \"[\", \"tau\", \"]\"}], \"]\"}]\)."` Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You might try [converting the `InterpolatingFunction` to a `Piecewise` one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169690/4999).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CreateDataSystemModel](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateDataSystemModel.html) to create a block from the `InterpolatingFunction` and then use this model as component. Since you plan to interpolate from an input `x`, you can choose the specification `"1D"`:

```
if = Interpolation[Transpose[{Range[0, 100], RandomReal[{0, 1}, 101]}]];

model = CreateDataSystemModel["MyModel.CTable", if, "1D"];
```

This extends a combi table using data that is written directly in the model (you can also use the `GeneratedAssetLocation` option if you instead want to print the data to a file that is then referenced in the model). You can also use a custom `SamplingPeriod` in the `CreateDataSystemModel` call to specify how to sample the `InterpolatingFunction` itself.

With this model available now you can choose how you want to add the differential equation. You can either create a model that uses the previous model as component and has the equation you indicated:

```
model1 = CreateSystemModel["MyModel.DiffEq", {"x" \[UndirectedEdge] "ct.u", "ct.y[1]"[t] == y'[t]}, t, {x \[Element] "RealInput", y \[Element] "RealOutput", ct \[Element] model}];
```

or you can instead do the integration with an integrator block, `Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.Integrator` :

```
model2 = ConnectSystemModelComponents["MyModel.WithIntBlock", {x \[Element] "RealInput", y \[Element] "RealOutput", ct \[Element] model, inte \[Element] "Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.Integrator"}, {"x" \[UndirectedEdge] "ct.u", "ct.y[1]" \[UndirectedEdge] "inte.u", "inte.y" \[UndirectedEdge] "y"}];
```