# Error when calling NMinimize on an InterpolatingFunction which depends on parameters

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to solve a basic calculus of variations problem numerically, by minimizing an integral over an Interpolating Function.

Basically this:

```
data = {1, x2, x3, 1};
f = Interpolation[data];
obj = Integrate[f[x]^2, {x, 1, 4}];
NMinimize[obj, {x2, x3}]
```

But I get an error

```
NMinimize::nnum: The function value [...] is not a number at {x2,x3} = {0.918621,0.716689}.
```

The function seems to be ok:

```
Block[{x2 = 0, x3 = 0.5}, f[2.5]]
0.15625
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:

Thank you for the answers, but I still don't understand *what* I'm doing wrong, only how I can change my code so Mathematica won't throw an error.

In particular:

1. `f[1.5]^2 /. {x2 -> 1, x3 -> 2}` and
   `((f /. {x2 -> 1, x3 -> 2})[1.5])^2` both evaluate without error, so why do I need to square my data instead of the `InterpolationFunction`?
2. Why does converting from an `InterpolatingFunction` to a piecewise polynomial fix the problem?

Also note that the code is just a MWE. The objective function would in general be a complicated function of `f` and its derivatives. For example
$$obj = f \sqrt{1+f'[x]^2}.$$
Now, I suppose I *could* resample that and generate a new InterpolationFunction
and then extract a piecewise polynomial of *that*. But why do I have to tie myself in knots like this? I can evaluate my objective at every point, so NMinimize should be able to do so as well, shouldn't it?

I'd like to treat the `InterpolationFunction` as I would any continuous function. I thought that was the point.

As I mentioned I'm trying  to numerically approximate a continuous solution, so the solution needs to be practical for having n variables instead of just 2.  The approximation would of course improve as n becomes larger.

I suspect this has something to do with evaluation order, but none of  I'm doing violates what I know about the Wolfram Language.

**Edit #2**:

Here is the actual (non-MWE) problem I'm trying to solve:

```
npts = 10;
vars = Unique[Table[x, npts]];
data = {1, Splice[vars], 1};
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
f2 = FunctionInterpolation[
   f[x] Sqrt[1 + f'[x]^2], {x, 1, Length[data]}];
obj = Integrate[f2[x], {x, 1, Length[data]}];
cons = Flatten[Table[{0 < x, x < 1}, {x, vars}]];
min = NMinimize[{obj, Splice[cons]}, vars];
ListPlot[data /. min[[2]]]
```

The solution should approximate a [Catenary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary).

Comment: Your problem lies with trying to square the `InterpolationFunction`.  Try something like `data1 = data^2; f1 = Interpolation[data1]; obj1 = Integrate[f1[x], {x, 1, 4}]; NMinimize[obj1, {x2, x3}]`.

Comment: If the data in the Q is your actual use-case, convert the interpolation to a piece wise polynomial. You can search on site for how to do that. For instance, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212753/4999 might do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want numerical optimization, use `NIntegrate`  and tell NMinimze x2,x3 are numerical values.

But be aware that it depends on the choosen `InterpolationOrder`

```
data = {1, x2, x3, 1};
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3];
obj[x2_?NumericQ, x3_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x]^2, {x, 1, 4}];
nmin = NMinimize[obj[x2, x3], {x2, x3}]
Plot[f[x]^2 /. nmin[[2]], {x, 1, 4}]

(*   {0.5, {x2 -> -0.111111, x3 -> -0.111111}}   *)

data = {1, x2, x3, 1};
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
obj[x2_?NumericQ, x3_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x]^2, {x, 1, 4}];
nmin = NMinimize[obj[x2, x3], {x2, x3}]
Plot[f[x]^2 /. nmin[[2]], {x, 1, 4}]

(*   {0.6, {x2 -> -0.2, x3 -> -0.2}}   *)
```

**Edit**

to do things analytically with Integrate, generate a second interpolation function f2 of f[x]^2 with `FunctionInterplation`  . But you may get a slight loss of precision, play with `Options[FunctionInterpolation]` to get best results, e.g. higher AccuracyGoal or more InterpolationPoints...

```
f2 = FunctionInterpolation[f[x]^2, {x, 1, 4}]//Quiet
```

Now you can integrate with Integrate and even minimize with `Minimize`

```
int2 = Integrate[f2[x], {x, 1, 4}] // Simplify

(*   (3 (349985 + 771384 x2^2 + 150015 x3 + 771384 x3^2 - 
     3 x2 (-50005 + 64261 x3)))/2000000   *)

min = Minimize[int2, {x2, x3}]

(*   {997/1999, {x2 -> -(2009/17991), x3 -> -(2009/17991)}}   *)

Plot[f2[x] /. min[[2]], {x, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: The main problem is, that Integrate can only work with the direct interpolated function f[x], but not with the squared f[x]2^2. But NIntegrate can. But you can go another way to get fully analytical solutions.  ........ See my edit.

Comment: Your use of `Quiet` silences errors which look pertinent. I wonder if the difficulties I'm having getting the correct solution are related.

Comment: Since you offer variables x2 and x3, FunctionInterpolation must complain, but it works nevertheless ( with my MMA version 8.0). The function values at interpolation points depend on x2,x2 as you see with `f2[[4]] // Simplify ` .   What do you mean with "correct" solution. As i said, it depends on interpolation order. If you want to get the same result with f2 and Integrate as with f and NIntegrate, choose high interpolation points, e.g. `f2 = FunctionInterpolation[f[x]^2, {x, 1, 4}, 
  InterpolationPoints -> 100] `