# Integrating and seeing an interpolating function

Tags: interpolation, calculus-and-analysis

I have the following piece of a Mathematica notebook:

---

[image]

---

As I understand, the interpolating function `M1hatInterp` is piecewise polynomial and hence can be integrated exactly. Why does `Integrate` not work here?

Is there a way around this? Also, is it possible to see what the piecewise interpolating function actually is?

Comment: Try `NIntegrate`. Or try converting the interpolating function into an explicit piecewise polynomial (see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59944/extracting-the-function-from-interpolatingfunction-object).

Comment: @MichaelE2 : Thank you for your comment. I did try M1hatInterp // PiecewiseExpand, but it does not do anything. I cannot use `NIntegrate`, since I need an exact result.

Comment: `PiecewiseExpand` isn't one of the methods in the linked Q&A. I like Carl Woll's method, personally. -- As a side note, if you post code people can play with, you're more likely to get a usable answer. I could make up my own function, but then I would solve my problem, not yours. And there's a good chance, you'll tell me that my method turns out not to work on yours, and I'll be mad about how I spent my time.

Comment: @MichaelE2 : Thank you again. Sorry, previously I missed the -- valuable -- link in your first comment.