# BVPh2.0 package

Tags: differential-equations

Is it possible to use BVPh2.0 package to solve ODE system of initial value problems? I need to solve an ODE IVP system using homotopy analysis method. I came through this package for solving the BVPs. So I need some suggestion regarding its usage. `NDSolve` is used to solve the ODE IVP system numerically. I need to find semi-analytical approximation for a nonlinear coupled ODE IVP using homotopy analysis method. But the package available to execute homotopy analysis method is BVPh2.0 which is for boundary value problem. That's why I have a doubt that shall we use it to solve IVP. Or else, is there any tools available in Mathematica to find analytical solution for nonlinear coupled ODE IVP

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange. It is not possible to recommend or reject options until you include the ODE that you want to solve (pasted as Mma code). It would be helpful to include the reasons that have prompted you to search for an external package and possibly why you think that it would work.

Comment: If it's a ODE IVP, why not directly use `NDSolve`? The ODE IVP solver of `NDSolve` is quite robust, if it cannot handle your problem, then probably there's something wrong with your ODE itself.

Comment: Use 'DSolve` to attempt to solve ODEs symbolically.  However, be aware that many ODEs do not have symbolic solutions.  More generally, you are more likely to obtain useful help from readers, if you provide more information.  Providing the ODEs themselves in Mathematica format would be best.

Comment: I never looked into BVPh package, but if I understand correctly, the semi-analytical approximation given by the package is rather complicated and I really doubt if the result is of much value. (If complicated analytic approximation is OK, why not rewrite `InterpolatingFunction` given by `NDSolve` with piecewise polynomial?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212753/1871