# VandermondeSolve changes, InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise breaks

Tags: linear-algebra, undocumented, compatibility, resourcefunction

I just notice [`ResourceFunction["InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise/) is broken in *v13.1*. (Perhaps it's in *v13.0*, I'm not sure. ) Here's a sample:

```
f = Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}];

pw[x_] = ResourceFunction["InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise"][f, x]
```

> `` LinearAlgebra`Private`VandermondeSolve::optx ``: Unknown option `Transpose` in `` LinearAlgebra`Private`VandermondeSolve[{0,1/3,2/3,1},{1,113/81,139/81,2},Transpose->True] ``.
>
> ……

The reason is clear: `InterpolatingFunctionToPiecewise` has called an undocumented function `VandermondeSolve` and it no longer owns the option `Transpose` in *v13.1*. But how to fix?

Comment: [`interpolationToPiecewise[f, x]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212753/4999) works...

Comment: MMA version 13.1 I get the same error messages