# Does FunctionRange work with Interpolation?

Tags: interpolation

```
$int = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}},   
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]
FunctionRange[{$int[x], x > 0.5}, x, y]
```

returns `Unable to find the range with the available methods.`

Of course `$int[1.2]` or any other value gives a number, so I am wondering if `FunctionRange` can work at all with interpolation. Any clue?

Answer (score 4):

With Carl Woll's [InterpolationToPiecewise](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212753):

```
(*https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212753*)
InterpolationToPiecewise[if_, x_] := 
  Module[{main, default, grid}, grid = if["Grid"];
    Piecewise[{if@"GetPolynomial"[#, x - #], x < First@#} & /@ 
      grid[[2 ;; -2]], if@"GetPolynomial"[#, x - #] &@grid[[-1]]]] /; 
   if["InterpolationMethod"] == "Hermite";

$int = Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]

FunctionRange[{InterpolationToPiecewise[$int, x], 
  x > 0.5 && LessEqual @@ Insert[First@$int@"Domain", x, 2]}, x, y]
```

> ```
> (*  0.5 < y <= 2.  *)
> ```

Comment: I wonder if the OP is looking for this? `Needs["DifferentialEquations\`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy\`"];`  `domain = InterpolatingFunctionDomain[$int]`

Comment: @CraigCarter `InterpolatingFunctionDomain[$int]` calls `$int["Domain"]`, so six of one, half-a-dozen of the other, imo. I never use the `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` package anymore. The package is short and can be inspected with ``NotebookOpen[FindFile["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"]]``. It consists of syntactic sugar for `if[meth]` for some of the methods found with `if["Methods"]`. It does have usage message that tell what the methods do, but just for the few it covers.

Comment: Note `MinMax[$int["ValuesOnGrid"]]` will give the range of the function values at the interpolation nodes. For `InterpolationOrder -> 1`, that will be equivalent to the entire function range (ignoring the constraint `x > 0.5`). It will also ignore any local extrema of the polynomial interpolants for higher-order interpolations. Thus it might be considered a quick approximation of the function range, which might be useful in some applications, especially when the grid-spacing is small.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Changing the data so that the function is not a straight line

```
$int[x_?NumericQ, order : _Integer?NonNegative : 1] :=
  Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}, InterpolationOrder -> order][x];
```

For `InterpolationOrder -> 1`

```
#[{$int[x], 0 <= x <= 2}, x] & /@ {NMinValue, NMaxValue}

(* {0., 2.} *)

% // RootApproximant

(* {0, 2} *)
```

For `InterpolationOrder -> 2`

```
#[{$int[x, 2], 0 <= x <= 2}, x] & /@ {NMinValue, NMaxValue}

(* {0., 2.04167} *)

% // RootApproximant

(* {0, 49/24} *)
```