# Fractional derivatives (FractionalD) of an InterpolatingFunction to retun another InterpolatingFunction

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, interpolation, fractional-calculus

## Question

I want to calculate the [`FractionalD`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FractionalD.html) of an `InterpolatingFunction` object, however, evaluating

```
FractionalD[Interpolation[Range[5]][x],{x,1/2}]
```

evaluates the argument but `FractionalD` remains unchanged, returning

```
FractionalD[ InterpolatingFunction[(* Something *)] ]
```

I would have expected an `InterpolatingFunction` object, the same output as `Interpolation[Sqrt[Range[5]]*2/Sqrt[Pi]]`

[image]

**How to calculate the fractional derivative of an [`InterpolatingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) so the output is another `InterpolatingFunction`?**

---

## Background

#### Fractional Derivatives

On the one hand, Wolfram Language (Mathematica) is fully capable of performing symbolic calculations of Fractional Derivatives defined as

[image]

For example,using [`FractionalD`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FractionalD.html), `FractionalD[f[x],{x,α}]` gives the *Riemann–Liouville* fractional derivative of order α of the function $f(x)$,

```
FractionalD[x,{x,1/2}]
```

[image]

#### Interpolating Functions

On the other hand, one can take derivatives of [`InterpolatingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) objects using [`D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) and [`Derivative`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html).

For example,

```
D[Interpolation[Range[9]][x],x]
```

[image]

Visually,

```
Plot[
    Evaluate[
        {
            Interpolation[Range[5]][x],
            D[Interpolation[Range[5]][x],x]
        }
    ]
    ,{x,0, 3}
]
```

[image]

---

## Due diligence

#### Web

I have searched the site and the web for the relevant keywords, unsuccessfully.

#### Piecewise (edited)

Thanks to @MichaelE2way for pointing out that [@CarlWoll 's  `InterpolationToPiecewise`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212753/10397) transforms an `InterpolatingFunction` (only `"Hermite"` [`Method`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method.html)) into a [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) object. In that particular case, the answer would be more straightforward, as  `FractionalD` does evaluate over `Piecewise` functions and one could re-build the `InterpolatingFunction` with [`FunctionInterpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionInterpolation.html). I'm still interested in alternative solutions.

#### NFractionalD

It seems [`NFractionalD`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NFractionalD.html) does work with `InterpolatingFunction`

```
NFractionalD[Interpolation[Range[9]][x], {x, 1/2}, 0.25]
```

But that would imply that I need to deconstruct the `InterpolatingFunction` to extract the data points to use `NFractionalD` in each point to then build a new `InterpolatingFunction` using [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html). That looks too cumbersome and error-prone.

Comment: To me, considering that `NFractionalD` does work, this seems like an oversight from *Wolfram Research,* `FractionalD` should work on `InterpolatingFunction`  natively.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59944/extracting-the-function-from-interpolatingfunction-object

Comment: Thanks@MichaelE2, I need to check in detail, but after a quick glance I gather these solutions work only for `InterpolatingFunction` defined by crossing points, but not by its derivatives, like this smooth staircase `Interpolation[Table[{{x},x,0,0,0,0},{x,0,9}]]`.

Comment: Carl Woll's `InterpolationToPiecewise` seems to give the exact form for whatever is the underlying interpoation order. I think my answer does order 3 only.